# sizeof(void*) and sizeof(function_type_ptr*) equality

Tags: c, standards, sizeof, c99

sizeof(void*) and sizeof(function_type_ptr*) equality

Must sizeof(void*) and sizeof(function_type_ptr*) be equal? Is it required by C (C90, C99) standard?

function_type_ptr is pointer to function.

This question is about **standard requirements**, not your own opinion. Please, give links, *section numbers and quotations* from standards

Comment: Is this a statement or a question

Comment: It is question about C language standard and its interpretation.

Comment: Hmm. What about "Fat pointers"? They are introduced in "J. L. Steffen. Adding run-time checking to the portable C compiler.
Software–Practice and Experience, 22(4):305–316, 1992." And "T. M. Austin, S. E. Breach, and G. S. Sohi. Efficient detection
of all pointer and array access errors. In Proceedings of the SIGPLAN’
94 Conference on Programming Language Design and
Implementation, 1994."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.

`6.2.6.1/2`: Except for bit-ﬁelds, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number, order, and encoding of which are either explicitly speciﬁed or implementation-deﬁned.

No such specification is done for function / void pointers.

Comment: Does standard states that pointers to different types are different and can have incompatible representation?

Comment: Yes, it says so, except for a few cases. See `6.2.5/27`

Comment: sorry, I have standard only in form of "The new C standard. An economic and Cultural Commentary". This book uses global numbering of lines. So, please, put here citation of  6.2.5/27

Comment: i can't cite it, it's too much. Please see yourself in the draft: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399003/is-the-sizeofsome-pointer-always-equal-to-four) the answer is no, there is no guarantee that even `sizeof(int*)` is the same as `sizeof(double*)`.

Comment: Can you give links to standards and its sections, which defines it?