# Comparing pointer to -1

Tags: c, pointers

I have a, rather philosophical, problem with verification of `shmat` function output.
Doing this:

```
void * addr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
if( addr == -1)
{
    perror("Uncool stuff");
}
```

gives me:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

And this is perfectly ok. Unfortunately, manual says:

```
Upon success, shmat() returns the address where the segment is attached; 
otherwise, -1 is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.
```

This is quite standard behavior, but how should I handle it? Is `if (addr == (void *) -1)` correct? I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377077/is-1-a-valid-pointer-address) and now I'm not really sure, if it would be 100% correct on every possible platform-blah-blah-blah ;-) I haven't found any other reliable sources on that matter.

I believe, that asking about signedness of pointers is a mistake, because pointers are not numbers. But in such case I'm not sure anymore...

**Edit**: this problem leads us to another question: is `char *addr = (char*)shmat(...)` correct? According to answers so far, it is, but if we consider no mmu, etc, etc... Yeah, maybe I'm losing touch with reality here, but I'm curious if there is **THE** proper way.

Comment: Since this is `shmat()`, the only platform you care about is POSIX. Also, you are not asking for the signedness of a pointer (that would be `addr < 0`, you are comparing against the constant `(void *) -1`.

Comment: Note the following paragraph from the POSIX rationale for the similar `mmap()`: _Existing  implementations  of  mmap()  return  the value -1 when unsuccessful. Since the casting of this value to type void * cannot be guaranteed by the ISO C standard to be distinct from a successful  value, this  volume  of  IEEE Std 1003.1-2001  defines the symbol MAP_FAILED, which a conforming implementation does not return as the result of a successful call._

Comment: That is very interesting, but keeps things complicated :) I might look for a similar symbol for `shmat()`. Thanks!

Comment: there is no similar constant for `shmat`. Anyway, this tells that the only reason to not use `-1` directly is that it could conceivably be returned by a `mmap()` operation (think `MAP_FIXED` on a !MMU platform), which I doubt happens in any implementation.

Comment: Anyway, existing practice in POSIX systems is to use `(void *)-1`

Comment: `dlsym()` is another interface with a "strange" way to check for errors. I think these are the only 3 functions that return pointers that don't return `NULL` on error.

Comment: this shows you just one thing, don't use `shmat` and other oldish SysV interfaces if you can avoid it. Modern POSIX systems have `shm_open` and `mmap`. Have a look into the linux man overview: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat) specifically says that `shmat` returns `(void*)-1` on error, so that's what you should compare the result to.  You might be looking at an older version of the documentation.  It's a bit of a hack, but it should be ok on any POSIX-conforming systems (it makes assumptions that aren't guaranteed by the C standard).  Converting the returned pointer to an integer type and then comparing to `-1` may or may not work; consider, for example, that `int` and `void*` might have different sizes.

Don't try to check `errno` without first checking the returned value.  In general, functions may set `errno` to some non-zero value even if they succeed.  Always check the returned value to detect failure, then you can check `errno` to determine the kind of failure.  And if you're going to check `errno`, be sure to set it to 0 before the call.  (I'm not sure that's strictly necessary in this case, but it's good practice.)

Comment: That is possible, that my manual is not up to date - I have a Polish system and I've found the quote on the web, in both cases no mention about casting. Thanks! I think about @ninjajl comment to my question, I'd have to make some research on that.

Comment: The version of the man page in the [Linux man pages repository](https://github.com/mkerrisk/man-pages.git) has used `(void*)-1` since  2005-12-02; it undoubtedly took a while for the change to propagate.  Disappointingly, IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (POSIX) says "... Otherwise, the shared memory segment shall not be attached, *shmat()* shall return -1, and *errno* shall be set to indicate the error.".

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's correct, but ugly.

For it to return -1 to you, it has to do the same kind of cast, so it should work on most platforms.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this test should work in nearly all cases
`if (addr == (void*)-1 ...`

If you really want to sidestep the issue, do

    `#include <errno.h>
    ...
    errno = 0;
    void * addr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (errno != 0) ...`

IOW use errno to detect the error rather than the return value from shmat.

(I would have a case in my unit tests for my assumptions; running them on a new platform would help you detect a bug caused by unexpected behavior on that platform.)

Comment: Checking errno is a nice solution, didn't think about it! It's clean and correct (if we forget about signals). Maybe it's not a 100% satisfying answer, but deftly +1 for it ;-)

Comment: Just checking `errno` is unsafe.  Functions can set `errno` to a non-zero value even on success; for example, a function might call another function that fails, but the caller succeeds.

Comment: Well, yes, but shmat does not. I think, that it is incorrect only if we consider signal handling.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I can't really say if it does or not, can I? Manual would not mention such behavior...