# What happens when you type cast an integer value into a char pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

For example,

```
char * integerToString(void);

int main() {
    char *myString;
    do {
        myString = integerToString();
    } while (myString == (char *)-1); // worked as intended
    free(myString);
    return 0;
}

char * integerToString(void) {

    int userInput;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &userInput);

    if (userInput < 0 || userInput > 99)
        return (char *)-1; // what happens here?

    char *myString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
    myString[0] = (int)floor(userInput/10.0) + '0';
    myString[1] = userInput%10 + '0';
    return myString;
}
```

and the program worked as intended, but what exactly happens when you type cast an integer value (without assigning the integer to a variable) into a character pointer? Will this program always work?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason one does not simply use `snscanf` here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306914/is-void-1-a-valid-address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C99:

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> 3. An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
>      `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a
>      pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal
>      to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> [...]
>
> 5. An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>      result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>      entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

So casting `-1` to a pointer has implementation-defined results. Therefore the answer is no: This is not guaranteed to work in general.

---

In particular: If it does turn out to be a trap representation, your code runs afoul of:

> **6.2.6 Representation of types**
>
> **6.2.6.1 General**
>
> [...]
>
> 5. Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored
>      value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does
>      not have character type, the behavior is undefined. If such a representation is produced
>      by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that
>      does not have character type, the behavior is undefined. Such a representation is called
>      a *trap representation*.

I.e. `while (myString == (char *)-1);` has undefined behavior if `myString` is a trap representation.

Comment: I don't see why it's not guaranteed to work in general. Why would it matter if the result is not correctly aligned, doesn't point to an entity of the referenced type, or is a trap representation? There's just a comparison for equality in the code. The pointer is never dereferenced. There's no reason for this not to work.

Comment: @Nikos C. On some weird implementations, you might have some variable `a` such as `(char*)&a == (char*)-1`

Comment: @NikosC. If it is a trap representation, then `myString == ...` has undefined behavior. And as Basile says, "implementation-defined" can also mean it inadvertently produces a pointer to an existing object in your code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That can't happen, because of `malloc(sizeof(char) * 2)`. The return value of `malloc()` cannot be `-1`. That would require one more `char` to allocated past `-1` which would overflow the maximum value of a pointer.

Comment: @NikosC. The return value of `malloc()` can be `(char *)-1` because `(char *)-1` can turn into anything the implementation wants. It's an arbitrary value.

Comment: What makes you think that `malloc` can *never* give `(char*)-1`. This is certainly true on  my Linux desktop, but could be false on some weird microcontroller.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Because two `char` were allocated. If the address of the first one is `(char*)-1`, the next one would have an address that's too big to fit in the pointer and would overflow. For example, if `ptr = malloc(2)` is `(char*)-1`, then  isn't `&ptr[1]`  NULL?

Comment: No, an address could be much wider than a `long` so you'll lose bits in the `(char*)-1` cast... Or might be non-unique (think of 1980 era x86 in 16 bits mode, segmented).

Comment: @NikosC. `(char *)-1` could produce `0x6f0a12`. I don't think you've realized what "arbitrary value" really means.

Comment: @NikosC. You're assuming the null pointer is represented as the integer 0 and that there's a straightforward mapping between integers and pointers.  The C standard guarantees neither.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens when you type cast an integer value into a char pointer?

In general, that is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (at least as soon as you dereference it). Be very [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). Read a lot more about UB (it is a tricky subject).

In some documented cases, you can case an `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` integral value into a valid pointer.

In your case, your heap allocated string is too short (so you have a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), which is one of the many examples of UB). You forgot the space for the terminating <kbd>NUL</kbd> byte, and you forgot to check against failure of `malloc`. BTW, `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1.

You could code:

```
if (userInput < 0 || userInput > 99)
    return NULL;

char *myString = (char *)malloc(3);
if (!myString) { perror("malloc myString"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
myString[0] = (int)floor(userInput/10.0) + '0';
myString[1] = userInput%10 + '0';
myString[2] = (char)0;
return myString;
```

On most systems (but not all), `(char*)-1` is never a valid address (always outside of the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)) and can never be given by system (or standard) functions. On My Linux/x86-64 desktop, I *know* that `(char*)-1` is not a valid address (e.g. because it is [`MAP_FAILED`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)), and I could (sometimes) use that as a sentinel non-null pointer value (which should *not* be derefenced). But that makes my code less [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability).

So you could decide and document that your `integerToString`  gives `(char*)-1` on non-integer input and `NULL` on heap allocation failure. That would work on my Linux/x86-64 desktop (so I sometimes do that). But that is not pure (portable) C11 code.

But if you stick to the C11 standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) it is implementation defined what and if `(char*)-1` is meaningful. It might be some [trap representation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6725981/841108) that you are not even allowed to compare (even if I don't know any actual C implementation doing that).

Actually your example illustrates that  *people never code for pure standard C11*; they always (and so do I) make **additional assumptions** on the C implementation; but **you do need to be aware of them**, and these assumptions could make the porting of your code to some hypothetical future machine a nightmare.

> Will this program always work?

This is a too general question. Your original program didn't even handle failure of `malloc` and had a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (because you forgot the space for the terminating zero byte). However, sadly for you, it would apparently often seems to work (and that is why UB is *so* scary). Consider however [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460584/841108) (standard conforming, but non-realistic) `malloc` implementation as food for thought.

<sup>(explaining exactly why your program appears to behave like you want is really difficult, because you need to dive into several implementation details)</sup>

Comment: Undefined behavior? If you *derefence* that pointer, it sure is undefined. But just abusing a `char *` as a `size_t` should be okay in itself.

Answer (score 1):

This program is an example of improper error handling. The value of `(char *)-1` appears to be implementation defined, see the other answers. Since this address is likely not a valid memory address that would be returned from `malloc`, this is used as a *sentinel value* in the program. The actual value is not of interest, it is compared to the same expression in the other function.

If you run this, `malloc` just *might* return whatever value that `(char *)-1` evaluates to. Then it will be interpreted as an error, although it is a valid memory address.

A better way would be to have an argument to `integerToString` of type `int *` and use this as a boolean to indicate failure. Then one would not reserve one `char *` value for error handling.

Or use C++ and an exception.

Comment: The result of `(char *)-1` is implementation defined. It's not necessarily all-bits-one. It's not an integer at all.

Comment: Since it is compared against exactly the same value in another piece in the code, it still works as a sentinel. I will fix my answer.

Comment: "*in the script*" which script?

Comment: @alk: I have been doing too much R lately, there the programs are usually called scripts.