# Why doesn't "gcc -Wall" warn for "if (ptr < 0)"?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, gcc-warning

*(A long story... you can directly jump to the question at the end...)*

I need to use `realpath(3)` so I wrote a simple example to try it:

```
$> cat realpath.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char pathname[PATH_MAX];

    if (realpath(argv[1], pathname) < 0) {
        perror("realpath");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", pathname);

    return 0;
}
$> gcc -Wall -o realpath realpath.c
$> ls /xxx
ls: cannot access '/xxx': No such file or directory
$> ./realpath /xxx/foo/bar
/xxx
```

The result of `./realpath /xxx/foo/bar` surprised me. According to the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) it makes more sense to fail with `ENOENT`. I even referred to the POSIX and found no answer. After quite some time I reread the manual and found `realpath(3)` returns `char *` rather than `int`. I was really irritated by `gcc`.

### Question

So **why** doesn't gcc (even with `-Wall`) warn about `if (ptr < 0)`?

Comment: Related: [How to turn on (literally) ALL of GCC's warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714827/how-to-turn-on-literally-all-of-gccs-warnings)

Comment: Because `0` is a perfectly legal *null pointer constant*. You are comparing the result of `realpath`, which is a pointer, with a null pointer. Not that it is legal, but this violation does not require a diagnostic.

Comment: Because comparing a pointer to 0 is well defined. It pretty much only makes sense to do that comparison for equality, but it seems the compiler doesn't really have that special case to a special case to warn for that (at least mine doesn't, maybe some newer versions of gcc do).

Comment: You always want to use -Wpedantic in addition to -Wall.

Comment: for me it's ok for `if (ptr == 0 /* NULL */)` or `if (ptr != 0)`. when does it make sense for `> 0` or `< 0`? i believe gcc has a good reason not to warn this by default. no?

Comment: @Art: I think less than comparison between pointers is only allowed, when they point to the same array.

Comment: @MikeMB Yup. But how is the compiler supposed to know that two pointers it has are to the same array? Especially since one of them is returned by a function that it knows nothing about. That's what I meant by a "special case", it is possible for the compiler to remember that one of the pointers involved in a comparison is a null pointer, but that requires extra effort. And it appears that newer versions of gcc do that effort. The older version I tried with doesn't.

Comment: There are some obscure systems that use negative addresses to separate "kernel space" from "user space".

Comment: @Lundin, this makes much sense.

Comment: @pynexj It really doesn't, but some badly-written programs/operative systems simply abuse the pointer type. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304795/can-a-pointer-address-ever-be-negative

Comment: i mean it makes sense to explain why gcc not giving warnings for this by default.

Comment: @Art: It knows that one of the operands is a nullptr, so the pointers can never point to the same array.

Comment: I personally use `-std=` together with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**`gcc -Wall` does not enable all of GCC's warnings!** See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714827/how-to-turn-on-literally-all-of-gccs-warnings) for more information.

In your case, you need to add the **`-Wextra`** flag:

```sh
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o realpath realpath.c
```

According to [**GCC's documentation**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> This enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by `-Wall`.
>
> The option `-Wextra` also prints warning messages for the following cases:
>
> - **A pointer is compared against integer zero with <, <=, >, or >=.**
> - [...]

Answer (score 5):

> So why doesn't gcc (even with `-Wall`) report a warning for `if (ptr < 0)`?

The name given to the `-Wall` flag is actually misleading, since it does not enable *all* compiler warnings.

You need to pass `-Wextra`. This way, you will get the following compiler warning:

```
warning: ordered comparison of pointer with integer zero [-Wextra]
```