# Why is 'IntPtr.size' 4 on Windows 64 bit?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I think I should get 8 when I use [IntPtr.Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.size). However, I still get 4 on a 64-bit machine with [Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) x64. Why?

Comment: Are you compiling your application as x86 (Properties > Build > Platform Target) rather than x64?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399003/is-the-sizeofsome-pointer-always-equal-to-four

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check your [file CPU architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-can-i-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64/270545#270545). Is it *x86*? It should be *Any CPU* or *x64*.

Answer (score 16):

The 64 bit operating system implements an emulated environment known as [WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/running-32-bit-applications) which emulates the 32 bit Windows environment. You are building your program targeting x86, i.e. 32 bit. That means that your process runs under the emulator as a 32 bit process and of course pointers are 4 bytes wide.

If you change your options to target x64 or AnyCPU then the pointer size will be 8 bytes when your process runs on a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the previous answers, even if you have selected the *Any CPU* architecture, [Visual Studio 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2013) has a new option in project properties called "Prefer 32-bit". You must turn it off on 64-bit development machines to get *IntPtr.Size = 8*.

Answer (score 1):

Check your build target: *x86*, *x64*, or *Any CPU*

If your configuration is *x86* or *Any CPU*, then, the intptr is 4 maybe.

More suggestions:

If you don’t have a requirement to run your program in x64 mode, please don’t change the build target to x64, because x64 mode has negative effects on both performance and space usage. I forgot the link of the original article on MSDN, but the main reason is the increase of pointer size and [GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) burden, you can search that article.