# c++ sizeof operator - pointer to double

Tags: c++, size, double, sizeof

I have unexpected outcome with sizeof operator (C++). In main class, I have these lines

```
 double * arguments_ = new double();
*arguments_  = 2.1;
*(arguments_+1) = 3.45;
 cout <<  (sizeof arguments_) << ' ' <<  (sizeof arguments_[0]) << ' '<< (sizeof arguments_)/(sizeof arguments_[0]);
```

which give me output
4 8 0

Double size is 8 bytes, and (sizeof arguments_[0]) = 8. However, why is (sizeof arguments_) not expressed in bytes as well (2*8 = 16)? Is sizeof operator applica

Comment: Yes, the size of a pointer is 4 bytes on your machine; the size of a pointer does not depend on what it points to. By the way, what's with ending your variable names with an underscore?

Comment: Note that `*(arguments_+1) = 3.45` is writing in an uninitialized memory area!

Comment: `arguments_` is a **pointer** to a `double`, not a `double`.

Comment: I don't know if this is "real" code, but *(agruments+1) is "the double that sits after the double allocated by your call to new double(). You're writing into a variable not allocated to you. Everything can happen, including everything going right, or your machine suddenly explode.

Comment: @Gui13, not uninitialized memory, it is writing to unallocated memory...

Comment: I think you've mistaken the size of a pointer as the size of **array** it points to. Although in your code, **arguments** is not a pointer to an array, either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the sizeof(some pointer) always equal to four?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399003/is-the-sizeofsome-pointer-always-equal-to-four)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both values are expressed in the same units. You have a 32-bit system, so the size of an address is 32 bits, or 4 bytes. The size of double on your system is 8 bytes. The result of an integer division `4/8` is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you apply **sizeof** operator to a pointer no matter what type it points, you will get the size of space the pointer occupies.

And in C++, a pointer variable occupies 4 bytes (on architectures with 32-bit address busses).

Comment: By the way, you should allocate **arguments** like this: double *arguments = new double[2], because you put 2 doubles in **arguments**.

Answer (score 2):

(sizeof arguments_) yields the size of your pointer which is 4 bytes.

Comment: In C++, pointer size is always 4 bytes no matter what it is pointing to.

Comment: In *32-bit C++*, that's true. In 64-bit, it's 64, and so on. Other than the platform differences, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

What you got is:

sizeof(pointer) = 4bytes

sizeof(double) = 8bytes

4/8 = 0  (remeber / is equal to integer division)