# what's the size of one node? and where is the data saved?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

As the question implies,what's the size of usual node:

```
struct node{
   int data;
   node* next;
};
```

If the struct holds the data and the address of next node, what's the size of the pointer address(not what it points to)?
Is there a difference if the next points to NULL?

where is the data(which is not a pointer) saved, stack or heap, if I made "new node":

```
node* linkednode= new node;
```

Are the answers change if I made class node?

Comment: That's implementation defined, we can't give you an answer, only your compiler on your platform can.

Comment: It depends. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/399003/78845

Comment: Think about the size and alignment of the members. Those put bounds on the size and alignment of the whole class. (Consider `node[N]`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check those using the `sizeof()` function applying it not only to your `int` and pointer variables but for the node itself. *Usually* `int`s and pointers are 4 bytes on 32 bit platforms, so this is implementation defined and might vary on other platforms. The total size of `node` might be equal to 8 but might not due to the cause specified above and\or data alignment.

Comment: "Usually" on 32-bit platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a structure is fixed, no matter what the member values are. In this case it's probably either 8 or 16 bytes (depending on if you are on a 32 or 64 bit platform). This will be reported if you check e.g. `sizeof(node)`.

The difference in size depending on 32 or 64 bit platforms, is because the pointer. Pointers are 32 bits (i.e. 4 bytes) on 32 bit platforms, and 64 bits (i.e. 8 bytes) on 64 bit platforms. The `int` type is *usually* 32 bits (4 bytes) on all platforms, but may be different on embedded systems or mainframes.

The reason it's not 12 bytes (4 + 8) on 64 bit platforms is because of alignment. The compiler will make sure that the pointer is on a good alignment to speed up access to that member.

Comment: I don't think it can sensibly be 12 bytes, unless there are some really weird alignment relaxations.

Comment: @KerrekSB You're probably right. Updated answer, with a small explanation of why.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I think the explanation is slightly off the point. Even if you reversed the member order, the size would be 16, not 12.

Comment: A lot of older PC's had 16 bit `int`; on them, size would have been 4 or 6, depending on the size of a pointer.  This might still be the case on some embedded systems.

Comment: @KerrekSB Probably qualifies as "really weird", but on a Unisys mainframe, the size would be 12: a 6 byte int and a 6 byte pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes on both counts, and +1 for the example :-)