# Cast union of pointers to void*

Tags: c++

I have union

```
union Data
{
   uint8_t * utf8;
   uint16_t * utf16;
   uint32_t * utf32;
};
```

and a variable `Data data;` How can I cast `data` to `void*`? The union size is equal to size of any pointer because It contains only pointers. So why I can't do this like `(void*)data`

Comment: Same reason that with `struct X {} x;` you cannot cast `x` to `void*` even though its size is no larger than that of `void*`.

Comment: If you to be really( again really) able to cast object of type `Data` to `void*` you can overload *typecast operator*

Comment: The correct way is to take the active member and then convert that to a `void*`.

Comment: Also, the C++ standard doesn't guarantee you that all sizes are the same, though in practice they are; see [Is the sizeof(some pointer) always equal to four?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399003/is-the-sizeofsome-pointer-always-equal-to-four)

Comment: Why do you need a union? Why not just keep it all as `void*`?

Comment: @MicroVirus, but when `sizeof(char*)` is 4 then `sizeof(void*)` will be 4, when `sizeof(char*)` is 8 `sizeof(void*)` will be 8?

Comment: @bajos In practice, yes, that is how it works, but it isn't guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Comment: @bajos it is guaranteed that `sizeof(char*)==sizeof(void*)`, but this is not guaranteed about any other type.

Comment: So if you set uint16_t x = 1; data.utf16 = &x; then you can't get a void* pointing to x unless you know that utf16 was the last element that was set.

Answer (score 1):

you can not cast `object` to `void*` but you can cast it's pointer to `void *` like this:

```
Data d;
void * d_ptr = (void *) &d;
```

and get object again like these:

```
Data &d2 = * (Data *) d_ptr;
Data *d3 = (Data *)d_ptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution:

```
    union Data
   {
      uint8_t * utf8;
      uint16_t * utf16;
      uint32_t * utf32;
      void* raw;
   };
```

When I return data.raw It should give result same (but without compilation error) as `(void*) data` (?).

Comment: This may work in practice, but it is not C++ standards compliant. See [Unions and type-punning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning). It may fail when compilers use aggressive optimisations based on strict aliasing.

Comment: You could also make raw a `uintptr_t'.

Comment: @MicroVirus Would the "volatile" keyword help prevent this behavior from the compiler?

Comment: @DrewBuckley It may or may not, depending on where you place the `volatile`. It isn't a total solution.

Comment: @MicroVirus `union { Data data; void* ptr; }` then?

Comment: @ChrisBecke Also technically not legal in C++ (though legal in C99 onwards). In practice, this answer works, but when looking at a standards point of view it's not legal code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use explicit cast using static_cast

```
Data d; 
int8_t s;
s = 0x11;
d.utf8 = &s;

void* p = static_cast<void*>(d.utf8);
uint8_t* utf8 = static_cast<uint8_t*>(p);
```

Comment: This is only half the story. If `utf16` was the active member, by setting `d.utf16 = ...`, then you'd need to also access that member, technically speaking, in `void *p = static_cast<void*>(d.utf16)`.

Comment: Unions will use the memory of the largest data member which in this case is a pointer. So I don't really get your point.

Comment: uint8_t* can be 8 bytes, while uint16_t* is 4 bytes. What would you expect if Data d contains 4 byte pointer and 4 byte rubbish and run your code?

Comment: As I said a union occupies only as much space as its largest member.