# String representation of time_t?

Tags: c++, timestamp

```
time_t seconds;
time(&seconds);

cout << seconds << endl;
```

This gives me a timestamp.  How can I get that epoch date into a string?

```
std::string s = seconds;
```

does not work

Comment: It is obscene how difficult and time consuming the solutions are. Instead of a simple function returning `std::string` and taking `time_t` and `string`for parameters, with the second being format definition, there are solutions taking more than half a dozen lines of code. Isn't this grand?

Comment: @ajeh: C++ is the Lego, not the Lego spaceship. ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << seconds;
std::string ts = ss.str();
```

A nice wrapper around the above technique is Boost's [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm):

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>

std::string ts = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(seconds);
```

And for questions like this, I'm fond of linking [The String Formatters of Manor Farm](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm) by Herb Sutter.

UPDATE:

With C++11, use [`to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Answer (score 44):

Try this if you want to have the time in a readable string:

```
#include <ctime>

std::time_t now = std::time(NULL);
std::tm * ptm = std::localtime(&now);
char buffer[32];
// Format: Mo, 15.06.2009 20:20:00
std::strftime(buffer, 32, "%a, %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", ptm);
```

For further reference of strftime() check out [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)

Comment: nulldevice, I wasn't clear above, but I wanted a string representation of the epoch date (timestamp).

Answer (score 5):

The top answer here does not work for me.

See the following examples demonstrating both the stringstream and lexical_cast answers as suggested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
 const char *time_details = "2017-01-27 06:35:12";
  struct tm tm;
  strptime(time_details, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
  time_t t = mktime(&tm); 
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << t;
  std::cout << t << "/" << stream.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Output: 1485498912/1485498912
Found [here](http://cpp.sh/72w6)

---

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>

int main(){
    const char *time_details = "2017-01-27 06:35:12";
    struct tm tm;
    strptime(time_details, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
    time_t t = mktime(&tm); 
    std::string ts = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(t);
    std::cout << t << "/" << ts << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 1485498912/1485498912
Found: [here](http://cpp.sh/73sl)

---

The 2nd highest rated solution works locally:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int main(){
  const char *time_details = "2017-01-27 06:35:12";
  struct tm tm;
  strptime(time_details, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
  time_t t = mktime(&tm); 

  std::tm * ptm = std::localtime(&t);
  char buffer[32];
  std::strftime(buffer, 32, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ptm);
  std::cout << t << "/" << buffer;
}
```

Output: 1485498912/2017-01-27 06:35:12 
Found: [here](http://cpp.sh/8ccns)

---

Comment: I don't get it. Your first two snippets show that the stringisation worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C++ does not have any time/date functions of its own - you need to use the C   [localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/) and related functions.

Comment: Your original question asked how to get a date, but it turns out that what you really wanted was the number of seconds as a string. It helps to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

the function "ctime()" will convert a time to a string.
If you want to control the way its printed, use "strftime".  However, strftime() takes an argument of "struct tm".  Use "localtime()" to convert the time_t 32 bit integer to a struct tm.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ way is to use stringstream.

The C way is to use snprintf() to format the number:

```
 char buf[16];
 snprintf(buf, 16, "%lu", time(NULL));
```

Comment: time_t isn't necessarily unsigned or of the same size as a long. In fact, it is usually signed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to

Answer (score 1):

Here's my formatter -- comments welcome.  This q seemed like it had the most help getting me to my a so posting for anyone else who may be looking for the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Parser.h"
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
string to_yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff();

string to_yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point pointInTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(pointInTime);
    microseconds micros = duration_cast<microseconds>(pointInTime.time_since_epoch());
    std::size_t fractional_microseconds = micros.count() % 1'000'000;

    std:stringstream microstream;
    microstream << "00000" << fractional_microseconds;
    string formatted = microstream.str();
    int index = formatted.length() - 6;
    formatted = formatted.substr(index);
    std::stringstream dateStream;
    dateStream << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_c), "%F %T") << "." << formatted;
    formatted = dateStream.str();

    return formatted;
}
```

Comment: Possibly not the best function name, and your code could do with some documenting comments ... but otherwise this isn't terrible ;)

Comment: I'd probably do a lot of things differently if do-overs were a real thing.  All I can really say is appreciate my .net's .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff") method more today than I did yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

There are a myriad of ways in which you might want to format time (depending on the time zone, how you want to display it, etc.), so you can't simply implicitly convert a time_t to a string.

The C way is to use [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/ctime/) or to use [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) plus either [localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/) or [gmtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/gmtime/).

If you want a more C++-like way of performing the conversion, you can investigate the [Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

localtime did not work for me. I used localtime_s:

```
struct tm buf;
char dateString[26];
time_t time = time(nullptr);
localtime_s(&buf, &time);
asctime_s(dateString, 26, &buf);
```