# C string representation of time_t

Tags: c, string, timestamp, type-conversion

I need to store time_t as a string in a char array. 
There are some other questions about converting time_t to string but they  are not helpful to me. i want to store the value of time_t in a string not to convert that to human readable format. Please take a look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997512/string-representation-of-time-t) before any answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm epoch_date;
    time_t Time_Epoch;
    strptime("2017 Jan 1 23:59:59", "%Y %b %d %T", &epoch_date);

    Time_Epoch = timegm(&epoch_date); // Time_Epoch: 1488268396
    return 0;
}
```

This piece of code returns timestamp as Time_Epoch.

How should i convert that timestamp to string to give desired output as follows:

The Desired output: `Current date and time are: 1488268396`

Comment: `printf("Current date and time are: %d\n", (int)Time_Epoch);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aim is to store the value of `time_t` in a char array, you can use `sprintf` as:

```
char strTime[50];
sprintf(strTime,"%d",Time_Epoch);
```