# Converting st_mtime into c++ string

Tags: c++, stat

I need to convert `st_mtime` returned from the `stat` structure as given here [man page for stat function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) into c++ string.

```
struct stat fs;
stat(some_path, &fs);
auto modificationTime = fs.st_mtime;

// Convert modificationTime into C++ string
```

How could I do this?

One of the solution I saw was `std::to_string(static_cast<long>(fs.st_mtime)))`. Could someone also explain what is happening here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997512/string-representation-of-time-t

Comment: Why did you tag `c`? are you interested in C based answers (ones that might get you a C string rather than a C++ String instance)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String representation of time\_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997512/string-representation-of-time-t)