# portable way to deal with 64/32 bit time_t

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, portability, time-t

I have some code which is built both on Windows and Linux.  Linux at this point is always 32-bit but Windows is 32 and 64-bit.  Windows wants to have `time_t` be 64-bit and Linux still has it as 32-bit.  I'm fine with that, except in some places `time_t` values are converted to strings.  So when `time_t` is 32-bit it should be done with `%d` and when it is 64-bit with `%lld`...

What is the smart way to do this?  Also: any ideas how I may find all places where `time_t`'s are passed to printf-style functions to address this issue?

---

**Edit:**
I came up with declaring `TT_FMT` as `%d` or `%lld` and then changing my `printf`s as in

```
printf("time: %d, register: blah")
```

to be

```
printf("time: " TT_FMT ", register: blah")
```

Is there a better way?  And how do I find them all?

Comment: Actually, I think you want to use unsigned format specifiers.

Comment: Tim, it is signed on both Linux and Windows (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to).  Otherwise, it wouldn't be able to represent Dennis Ritchie's entire life. ;) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Representing_the_number)

Comment: Actually, time_t is also 64 bits wide on contemporary glibcs for Linux x86_64.

Comment: @user562374 only on 64-bit Linux. 32-big glibc has just got 64-bit time_t support in [version 2.32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60709400/995714)

Comment: It is not Windows that determines the size of  `time_t`, but rather the C library you are using. For example in MSVC you can define `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` to force 32 bit time.  However I am pretty sure that the assertion _"Linux at this point is always 32-bit"_ is untrue.  It is messier than that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the C standard, `time_t` is an arithmetic type, "capable of representing times".  So, it could be `double` for example.  (Posix [mentions this more explicitly](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html), and also guarantees that `time()` returns the number of seconds since the Epoch—the latter is not guaranteed by the C standard.)

Maybe the cleanest solution is to convert the value to whatever type you want.  You may want one of `unsigned long long` or `unsigned long`:

```
printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)t);
```

Comment: This has always seemed like the cleanest method to me.  It seems a pity that `printf` didn't include a format specifier for `time_t` values, even if it was just the `%c` behaviour from `strftime`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I like it, except time_t is signed; I'll probably use int64_t.

Comment: How about `%jd` and `intmax_t`?

Comment: @JL2210 Yeah, that should work.. although I _think_ `"%" PRIdMAX` might be more portable.

Answer (score 7):

I think the only truly portable way is to use `strftime` to convert the `time_t` to a string.

If you're sure that you're only operating on platforms where `time_t` is an `int`, you could cast to `intmax_t` (from `stdint.h`) and print it using `PRIdMAX` (from `inttypes.h`).

Comment: Now, (9 years after this answer), you could use `%jd` in place of `PRIdMAX` as in `snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%jd", (intmax_t)i_am_a_time_t_var)`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go with the macro specifier, I would recommend one minor tweak.  Instead of encapsulating the entire specifier, encapsulate just the modifier:

```
#ifdef 64_BIT_TIME
  #define TT_MOD "ll"
#else
  #define TT_MOD ""
#endif
```

and then using it like this:

```
printf("current time in seconds is: %" TT_MOD "u", time(0));
```

The reason why is that while you primarily want the second in decimal, every so often you may want hex (or perhaps you want leading 0's).  By only having the modifier there, you can easily write:

```
"%" TT_MOD "x"   // in hex
"%08" TT_MOD "d"  // left pad with 0's so the number is at least 8 digits
```

Comment: Minor nitpick; macro names can't start with digits.  I would probably go for a name more like the `<inttypes.h>` names, without encroaching on the reserved namespace (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.31.6 _Macros that begin with either PRI or SCN, and either a lowercase letter or X may be added to the macros defined in the `<inttypes.h>` header_).

Answer (score -1):

Slight adjustment on Alok's answer, it's signed on both Windows and Linux, so:

```
printf("%lld\n", t);
```

is cleaner.