# Getting file date modified in C using cross-platform code

Tags: c, linux, windows, cross-platform

I wanna write a program that get the last modified date of a file. I wanna compile this code in windows, linux and mac ...

**sys/stat.h** is for linux only

I can't find a cross-platform library that do this! Should I use something like this:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#ifndef st_mtime
#define st_mtime st_mtimespec.tv_sec
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: You have to write the code for each pataform yourself. This shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: And standard C runs on platforms which has no file change time, too. That´s one reason why there isn´t something like that.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342789/how-to-get-file-modification-time-in-c-under-multiple-os