# Converting UtcTimeOnly to millisecond in QuickFIX/C++

Tags: c++, quickfix

I'm using QuickFIX/C++ and I want to convert MDEntryTime field, which is UtcTimeOnly object, to milliseconds.

```
FIX::UtcTimeOnly to;
std::cout <<static_cast<unsigned long>(to.getTimeT());
```

this gives incorrect values.
This same approach works work UtcTimeStamp objects.

what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation it looks like:

```
to.getTimeT() * 1000 + to.getMillisecond()
```

Should work. It will return incorrect values if you are on an ancient compiler with 32-bit `time_t` though.

Comment: Is there a question? Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467418/portable-way-to-deal-with-64-32-bit-time-t will help?