# How is time_t defined?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is ultimately a time_t typedef to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to)

In /usr/include/time.h time_t is defined as `typedef __time_t time_t`. What does this mean exactly? Is the type of time_t compiler specific? I have heard it is by default a `long` value.

Comment: You could have searched further. There's `#include "bits/types.h"`. But after that, you possibly would have landed here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says:

> 7.23.1
>
> The types declared are [...] time_t [...] which  are  arithmetic  types capable of representing times

You just need to retain that it is an arithmetic type: you can perform arithmetic with values of `time_t` type.