# Why do I get a warning about possible loss of data when seeding the random number generator from time(NULL)?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

am learning vectors and made a bit of code that selects random numbers i can use for buying lottery tickets here in Netherlands. But although it runs, the compiler is warning me about 'conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int, possible loss of data'.

Can anyone spot what is causing this? I haven't even defined any unsigned int in this code; int i by default is a signed int as i understand. Thanks for insight.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void print_numbers();
string print_color();

int main() {
srand(time(NULL));
print_numbers();
string color = print_color();
cout << color << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

//Fill vector with 6 random integers. 
//
void print_numbers() {
vector<int> lucky_num;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    lucky_num.push_back(1 + rand() % 45);
    cout << lucky_num.at(i) << endl;
}
}

//Select random color from array.
//
string print_color() {
string colors[6] = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "green", "purple"};
int i = rand()%6;
return colors[i];
}
```

Exact compiler message: warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data. Line 11.

Comment: It is really exciting to guess when we don't know exact compiler message and code line. However, information about lottery tickets in Netherlands really helps :)

Comment: Warning message gives you a line, you should have mentioned this important info in the post (preferably full warning msg).

Comment: The warning would be on line 'srand(time(NULL));' which thats the only one talking about time. For the future a line number would indeed help.

Comment: Does anyone know the random number seed used in the Netherlands lotto draw? It'd really help me out:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `time_t` happens to be larger in size than `unsigned int` on your particular platform, you get such a warning. Casting from a "larger" to a "smaller" type involves truncating and loss of data, but in your particular case it doesn't matter so much because you are just seeding the random number generator and overflowing an `unsigned int` should occur for a date in the very far future.

Casting it to `unsigned int` explicitly should suppress the warning:

```
srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 1):

`time_t` is a 64 bit value on many platforms to prevent the epoch time eventually wrapping while `unsigned int` is 32 bits.

In your case, you don't care cause you're just seeding the random number generator. But in other code, if your software ever deals in dates [past 2038](http://technopark02.blogspot.com/2004/12/unix-year-2038-rollover-problem.html), you could have your `time_t` truncated to a 32-bit pre 2038 date when you cast to a 32-bit value.

Answer (score 0):

[time](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/) returns a `time_t` object.

[srand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) is expecting an unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

This line can overflow if the return value from `time` exceeds the representation range of an `unsigned int`, which is certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
void srand ( unsigned int seed );
time_t time ( time_t * timer );
typedef long int __time_t;
```

long int is not the same as a unsigned int. Hence the warning.

(from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to)