# warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data -- C++

Tags: c++

I made a simple program that allows the user to pick a number of dice then guess the outcome... I posted this code before but with the wrong question so it was deleted... now I cannot have any errors or even warnings on this code but for some reason this warning keeps popping and I have no clue how to fix it...
**"warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data"**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int  choice, dice, random;

int main(){
    string decision;
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    while(decision != "no" || decision != "No")
    {
        std::cout << "how many dice would you like to use? ";
        std::cin >> dice;
        std::cout << "guess what number was thrown: ";
        std::cin >> choice;
         for(int i=0; i<dice;i++){
            random = rand() % 6 + 1;
         }
        if( choice == random){
            std::cout << "Congratulations, you got it right! \n";
            std::cout << "Want to try again?(Yes/No) ";
            std::cin >> decision;
        } else{
            std::cout << "Sorry, the number was " << random << "... better luck next  time \n" ;
            std::cout << "Want to try again?(Yes/No) ";
            std::cin >> decision;
        }

    }
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I am trying to figure out, why am I getting this warning:
warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

Comment: The `time_t` might be a 64-bit type, while `int` is 32 bits.

Comment: And, please, for the love of whatever gods you believe in, choose C or C++ and stick with it. Including `cstdlib` and `time.h` makes me want to come over and slap you around :-)

Comment: LOL! Paxidiablo I would LOVE to stick with C++ but this class requires me to start with C/C++ then migrate more into C++ and ditch the C as much as possible

Comment: No it does not. You can include `ctime` instead of `time.h`.

Comment: @aib indeed, but it could have been more explicitly stated.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

That's because on your system, `time_t` is a larger integer type than `unsigned int`.

- `time()` returns a `time_t` which is probably a 64-bit integer.
- `srand()` wants an `unsigned int` which is probably a 32-bit integer.

Hence you get the warning. You can silence it with a cast:

```
srand ( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );
```

In this case, the downcast (and potential data loss) doesn't matter since you're only using it to seed the RNG.

Comment: +1 this is only correct answer in its entirety (and wordings).

Comment: Ugh, C-style casts don't belong in C++ programs.

Comment: @aib They are shorter. And they [are fine for numerical casts.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1255015/922184)

Comment: Worked it like a charm for me. And I guess you could use size_t instead of unsigned int, isn't it?
Thanks!

Comment: @Fabiano You *could*. But bare in mind that `srand()` takes `unsigned int` as a parameter. If `unsigned int` and `size_t` happen to be different sizes on your machine (as is usually the case on x64), then you will get a similar warning about potential loss of data. So it's better to stick with just `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 10):

This line involves an implicit cast from `time_t` which `time` returns to `unsigned int` which `srand` takes:

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
```

You can make it an explicit cast instead:

```
srand ( static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)) );
```

Answer (score 2):

`time()` returns a `time_t`, which [can be 32 or 64 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to). `srand()` takes an `unsigned int`, which is 32 bits. To be fair, you probably won't care since it's only being used as a seed for randomization.

Comment: They are not guaranteed to be 32/64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

This line involves an implicit cast from time_t which time returns to unsigned int which srand takes:

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
```

You can make it an explicit cast instead:

```
srand ( static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)) );
```