# C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'std::streamsize' to 'size_t', possible loss of data

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have migrated my VC++ project form VS2008 to VS2013 and got some warnings like:

> `C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'std::streamsize' to 'size_t', possible loss of data.`

How can I resolve these type of warnings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time\_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data -- C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246536/warning-c4244-argument-conversion-from-time-t-to-unsigned-int-possible)

Comment: @rkm_Hodor_king Not really.

Answer (score 1):

As it's stated in the [c++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize), `std::streamsize` is defined as `signed` (emphasis mine):

> The type `std::streamsize` is a signed integral type used to represent the number of characters transferred in an I/O operation or the size of an I/O buffer. It is used as a **signed counterpart of `std::size_t`**, similar to the POSIX type `ssize_t`.

Anyways, the exact implementation seems not to be specified.

Usually a conversion from `signed` to `unsigned` type with the same base (e.g. `long`) shouldn't issue a warning about possible data loss (unless using the sign indicator is meant).

It's probably a poor implementation in Visual Studio C++.

Comment: What about `unsigned int u = (int)-1;`? What would you expect `u` to be? Would you consider this data loss? Should the compiler issue a warning?

Answer (score 1):

In MSVC 2013 `std::streamsize` is:

```
typedef _Longlong streamsize;
typedef _LONGLONG _Longlong;
#define _LONGLONG   __int64
```

And `size_t` is:

```
typedef unsigned __int64    size_t;
```

Thus an easy repro case is:

```
unsigned __int64 b = 1;
__int64 a = b;
```

However this doesn't issue a warning - so probably you redefined `size_t` somewhere to be 32bits?

For clarity:

```
std::streamsize b = 1;
size_t a = 0;
b = a;
```

Also issues no warning.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use. According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize),

> Except in the constructors of std::strstreambuf, negative values of std::streamsize are never used.

So you can safely cast your signed value.

```cpp
std::streamsize i;
// ...
size_t u = static_cast<size_t>(i);
```

However, in the more general case (as opposed to what πάντα ῥεῖ wrote), I think the warning is valid (even though `gcc` doesn't spit a similar one out). When comparing signed and unsigned values, it's best to be explicit what you mean.

You can force unsigned-ness, e.g. using a code snippet such as the following (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762110/partial-template-specialization-based-on-signed-ness-of-integer-type) for the general form):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_signed<T>::value, typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type >::type
force_unsigned(T u) {
        if (u < 0) {
                throw std::overflow_error("Cannot use negative value as unsigned type");
        }
        return static_cast< typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type >(u);
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_signed<T>::value, T >::type
force_unsigned(T u) {
        return u;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << force_unsigned((unsigned int)1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << force_unsigned((int)1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << force_unsigned((int)0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << force_unsigned((int)-1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```