# How can I convert time in ms to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' format?

Tags: facebook, lua, saas, coronasdk

I write mobile application  with Corona SDK that interacts with Facebook.

On user's Facebook login I receive "expiration of access token" from Facebook in ms.
I want to send it to Parse.com (SAAS) in the yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' date format.

How can I do it?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378822/getting-previous-days-date-in-lua.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date = os.date("!%Y-%m-%dT%H:%m:%S.000Z")
```

You'll have to leave the milliseconds as 0, because you can't get those from `os.date`. Also the `!` at the start is required to get UTC time (as opposed to local time), which is what the `Z` at the end signifies.

[More info.](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

The LuaDate library apt for Date Manipulationss 
http://luaforge.net/projects/date/

It is very easy to use, and it is documented well!
You can download it from here
http://files.luaforge.net/releases/date/date

There may be other easier ways as well.