# Display POSIX as Calendar Date without gmtime and asctime

Tags: c, date, time, time.h

I currently have a double containing a POSIX time stamp, and I am successfully using gmtime and asctime to display a calendar date via a time_t struct:

```
    time_t input = posix;
    printf("%s",asctime(gmtime(&input)));
```

This works well, except (obviously) when the POSIX time falls outside the time.h library's limits (i.e. 1901-2038), in which case it returns a date in 1901. Are there any easy alternatives to gmtime/asctime/time.h, or am I simply going to have to work with the raw figures?

Edit: I should add that having a result that falls outside those limits is fairly likely, as the posix double is the result of a calculation, rather than an instantiation of the current system time.

Comment: How do you expect an international standrad to be displayed as a calendar date?

Comment: By calendar date I mean a representation separated into year, month, day, etc. In the above case, when the content of double posix is 1235736569.980815, it correctly returns Fri Feb 27 12:09:29 2009.

Comment: I hardly think there is a viable alternative to `time.h` covering the 2038 problem. You sure you need to cover dates over 20 yrs from now? :)

Comment: Yeah absolutely certain I need to cover dates beyond 2038 and before 1901...

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Wikipedia entry on Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> The POSIX and Open Group Unix specifications include the C standard library, which includes the time types and functions defined in the `<time.h>` header file. The ISO C standard states that `time_t` must be an arithmetic type, but does not mandate any specific type or encoding for it.

If you need to handle a large range of times in a portable manner, you will probably have to use your own time library.  I don't think you can even count on `struct tm` covering a range beyond 1901 to 2038.

You might also want to read this [StackOverflow answer regarding time_t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/471287/266392).