# difftime is returning a wrong number

Tags: c++, ctime, difftime

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double seconds;    
    struct tm birth = {0}; //10-28-1955
    birth.tm_year = 55;
    birth.tm_mon = 9;
    birth.tm_mday = 28;
    birth.tm_sec = 0;

    struct tm present = {0}; //2-10-2021 
    present.tm_year = 121;
    present.tm_mon = 1;
    present.tm_mday = 10;
    present.tm_sec = 0;

    time_t p1 = mktime(&present);
    time_t b1 = mktime(&birth);
    seconds = (difftime(p1, b1));
    seconds /= 86400;
    cout << "Bill "
         << "Gates- " << seconds << "days" << endl;
}
```

Output :

```
Bill Gates- 18668.2days
```

I'm trying to use `<ctime>` to try to find the number of days Bill Gates has been alive up to 2-10-2021. I get an answer of 18668.2; that is way off, as it should actually be around 20000 days.

[image: code with output]

While debugging, everything runs fine until line 21.

[image: on line 21]

When it reaches line 22, `b1` becomes -1.

[image: on line 22]

I'm not sure how to fix this. The date I'm putting in for `struct birth` seems fine.

Comment: Please edit your code and output into the question as text.

Comment: [`mktime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime) behavior for dates before the epoch (1970) is implementation defined, see [mktime returns -1 when given a valid struct tm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127013/mktime-returns-1-when-given-a-valid-struct-tm) for example.

Comment: 2000 days is less than 10 years.  How old is Windows, again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When it reaches line 22, b1 becomes -1.

Sorry, but your C standard library is not enough to handle your dates. Use (or write) a different library that will allow to represent time before year 1970.

While at it, you are using C++ - no need to use C functions. Try using [chrono library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) that is part of C++ standard library.