# Convert a timestamp as a long to struct tm

Tags: c, timestamp

I've a `long` as: `1459791437` and I want to transform it in this format: `YYYYMMDD,HH`.
I don't know how to convert that `long` in a `struct tm`, I need that conversion to use the function: `strftime`.

Here you can see what I want to do:

```c
 void find_date(long timestamp, int *date, int *hour){
    char buf[20];
    struct tm *time_struct = magic_function(timestamp);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y%m%d,%H", time_struct);
    printf("Time: %s", buf);
}
```

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679022/converting-from-an-integer-epoch-time-value-to-local-time) but it doesn't print anything:

```c
void find_date(long timestamp, int *date, int *hour){
    char buf[20];
    struct tm *timeinfo;
    
    /* Conversion to time_t as localtime() expects a time_t* */
    time_t epoch_time_as_time_t = timestamp;
    /* Call to localtime() now operates on time_t */
    timeinfo = localtime (&epoch_time_as_time_t);
    
    strftime (buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y%m%d,%H", timeinfo);
    
    printf("Test: %s", buf);
}
```

What I cannot do is the `struct tm *magic_function(long)`, could anyone help me?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679022/converting-from-an-integer-epoch-time-value-to-local-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Unix timestamp to DateTime and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa)

Comment: @Lashane C and C# are not the same language, I don't get how these 2 can be duplicate

Comment: @Timmy picked wrong question from the millions of the duplicates

Comment: @Harry I've tried that solution but gives me 2 warning and doesn't print anything

Comment: @Lashane I've looked for these duplicates, but I haven't found anyone working.

Comment: Your code fragments look fine.  You may just be having the buffered output problem.  Try `printf("Test: %s\n", buf)`, or `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: @SteveSummit The program keep crashing and I don't get why. It doesn't print anything

Comment: Are you doing `#include <time.h>`?

Comment: Your code works for me, so your crash must be due to something you haven't shown us.  How are you calling `find_date`?

Comment: Before attempting `strftime()`, insure the pointer `struct tm *timeinfo` is not `NULL`.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thank you! I haven't included that library! Now everything works well.

Comment: Detail: `#include <time.h>` includes a header file for code. If does not cause a library to be included.

Comment: @chux you're right, I used to program in Java.

Comment: Welcome to C, coding without a net and without training wheels.

Comment: @Timmy Glad to hear that the `#include` line helped, but please also take chux's suggestion to check the return value from `localtime` to make sure it's not null.

Comment: @SteveSummit Done! Thank you!