# C function printf() limited in length?

Tags: c

Upon calling the sprintf function to format a string, something unexpected was printed

```
printf("%d;%s;%s;%d;%d;\n", ptr->programmaType, ptr->titel, ptr->zender, ptr->start, ptr->einde);
```

prints "0;Stargate;scifi;0;0;" while

```
printf("%d;", ptr->einde);
```

prints "42", which is the value of ptr->einde. I've also tried

```
printf("%d;%s;%s;%d;%d;", 0, "Stargate", "scifi", 0, 42);
```

which prints correctly, so I'm guessing the problem is related to the variables. Last thing I tried was

```
int bug = ptr->einde;
printf("%d;%s;%s;%d;%d;\n", ptr->programmaType, ptr->titel, ptr->zender, ptr->start, bug);
```

which also failed to print correctly... I have no idea what the hell is happening.

Note: ptr->start and ptr->einde are defined als time_t types, but seeing as printf works with a single argument I doubt that's a problem.

Comment: Not strictly related to your problem, but please don't write code in Dutch. It's a bad habit.

Comment: Could you perhaps show little more context for the code? For example, how you get the `ptr`? Are you perhaps returning it as a pointer to a local variable in a function?

Comment: Normally I wouldnt, but our professor forced us to use a struct he wrote, in dutch :(

Comment: When looking at variables in your debugger, what do you see? printf() does not have a length limitation.

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit platform?

Comment: What type is "zender"?

Comment: `"%d"` is for `int`; probably `ptr->einde` is something else which is just plain wrong: use the correct specifier.

Comment: @Andreas I'm running Visual Studio 2008 on a x64 platform

Comment: @pmg why then does it print correctly when I call printf with only the ptr->einde

Comment: @pmg exactly - Jelco, this could be worth checking out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to

Comment: The mehanics of **UB** (Undefined Behaviour) are strange :)

Comment: That's not the reason of the problem, but you better use %ld to print a time_t variable.

Comment: `time_t` is probably a 64 bit integer value. The solution is to cast your variable to `(uint64_t)` and using `PRIu64` format specifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said that `ptr->start` and `ptr->einde` are `time_t` type. This type is not not fully portable  and can be any ["integer or real-floating type"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html), so it's possible that they are not being handled correctly on your system when you try to print them as `int` types.

Try casting it to something known and then printing:

```
printf("%d;%s;%s;%ld;%ld;\n", ptr->programmaType, ptr->titel, 
    ptr->zender, (long)ptr->start, (long)ptr->einde);
```

Comment: This works! I am still puzzled as to why printf("%d", ptr->einde) does print "42", but at least I've got something working now.

Comment: Check out pmg's comments. It's UB. UB is always puzzling. ;)

Comment: This is what probably happens: If `ptr->start` is a 64 bit value and if `int` is 32 bits, then the last two `%d` specifiers will print the high 32 bits and the low 32 bits of `ptr->start`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your definition of `ptr->einde` is **not** of type `int`.

And you are using `"%d"` in the `printf` specifier which expects an `int` value.
Use the correct specifier for the correct type and printf behaves.

Comment: I initialised an int to 53, and replaced the time_t with this integer. It still prints this int as "0" in the long printf, while it prints correctly if I call printf("%d", int)

Comment: @JelcoAdamczyk – that’s because there are 2 `time_t`s in your long call, if you replaced both `ptr->start` and `ptr->einde` to `int` you wouldn't see it acting strangely

Comment: Yep, using the wrong match for specifier and value invokes Undefined Behaviour. You don't want **UB** in your programs. Always correctly match the specifier and the values (with casts if needed).

Answer (score 0):

No `printf` is not limited in length, except in embedded implementations where it must be able to print at least 4095 chars.

`time_t` is probably a 64 bit integer value. The solution is to cast your variable to `(uint64_t)` and using `PRIu64` format specifier.

```
printf("%d;%s;%s;%"PRIu64";%"PRIu64";\n", 
           ptr->programmaType, 
           ptr->titel, ptr->zender, 
           (uint64_t)ptr->start, 
           (uint64_t)ptr->einde);
```