# What is the time_t type in linux

Tags: c++, linux, time, types

I'm newbie in C/linux. `man time_t` is unsuccess. I'm trying to clarify what exactly `time_t` type is? It's ok when I'm assign `const int` to the variable type `time_t` as follows:

```
time_t =4;
```

Seems this type is just alias for some numeric type. But I don't understand what is this type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to

Comment: `man time_t is unsuccess`. I recommend you in this case `man -K time_t`. `man -K`: Search for the specified string in *all* man pages. Warning: this is probably very slow!

Comment: What is your problem ? What are you trying to achieve ? Who cares what this type is ! It just the type of the value returned by the `time()` function, period.

Comment: A better man page to read is [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is usually an alias, but it is standard type in C/C++. It can be used not only in Linux.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/

> time_t
>
> Time type
>
> Alias of a fundamental arithmetic type capable of representing times, as those returned by function time.
>
> For historical reasons, it is generally implemented as an integral value representing the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC (i.e., a unix timestamp). Although libraries may implement this type using alternative time representations.
>
> Portable programs should not use values of this type directly, but always rely on calls to elements of the standard library to translate them to portable types.