# printf output is null when combined with an int C

Tags: c, string, logging, null, printf

I have a problem with my log function, I tried to create a log method, which prints the current time in brackets before, but it don't work. Every time null is printed instead of the string.

This is my `log` function:

```
void log(char *szDebugString)
{
    printf("%s", szDebugString); //only for debug

    time_t currentTime;

    time(&currentTime);

    printf("%s", szDebugString); //only for debug
    printf("[%d] %s\n", currentTime, szDebugString);
}
```

Now when i'm calling the function:

```
log("test\n");
```

I get the following output on the console(time variies):

```
test
test
[1414078074] (null)
```

So my question is, why the string in the third `printf` is null?

[image: Last test]

Comment: change the name of your function `log` it is already defined in `math.h`

Comment: i'm not including math.h

Comment: If you call `printf("%s", szDebugString)` after `printf("[%d] %s\n", currentTime, szDebugString);` what does it output? Is it null as well?

Comment: What do you get if you print time and string in reverse order? And what happens when you write `(int)currentTime` instead?

Comment: My compiler warned my when I used the function name log() 
warning: conflicting types for built-in function \u2018log\u2019

Comment: what should i say? It don't work at my code, i'm using VStudio Express 2013.

Comment: Use `%ld` for `currentTime`.

Comment: The name `log` is reserved whether you've included `<math.h>` or not. Change the name of the function and change the `printf` call to something like `printf("[%ld] %s\n", (long)currentTime, szDebugString)`. If you still see the problem after doing that, let us know, and show us a complete self-contained program that exhibits the problem. What OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: @1336087: Using `%ld` is no better than using `%d`. `%d` requires an `int` argument; `%ld` requires a `long int` argument. `time_t` is not necessarily either.

Comment: your code works with log function in ideone : http://ideone.com/p7yRff

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes you are correct, OP should cast it to `long` before printing it.

Comment: @1336087: "cast", not "typecast". Typecasting is something that happens to actors.

Comment: Screenshots are not particularly useful. You've already shown us the output as text.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thanks for correcting me :) However on many sites I see it as typecast.

Comment: @1336087: Yes, many sites get it wrong.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thank you :) I now know what is correct term for it.

Comment: Solution is casting currentTime to long

Comment: to use the time() function, the code needs to have the line: #include <time.h>  which will also define the 'time_t' type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of [time_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) is unspecified and it not always *int* in a test I just did it is actually *long*, and `clang` gives me this warning (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fad0e198bfa968e0)*):

```
warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'time_t' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
printf("[%d] %s\n", currentTime, szDebugString);
         ~~         ^~~~~~~~~~~
         %ld
```

Passing an invalid specifier to `printf` is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), possibly `printf` is using the extra bytes from `currentTime` when processing the `%s` format specifier.

As Keith Thompson points out there is no format specifier for *time_t* but you can convert it to a known type such as *long*:

```
printf("[%ld] %s\n", (long)currentTime, szDebugString);
         ^^^         ^^^^^^
```

Note, that [log](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log) is used in the standard library and you should not be using that name.

Comment: There's no built-in format for printing a `time_t` value, but you can convert it to a known type. Try this: `printf("[%ld] %s\n", (long)currentTime, szDebugString);`

Comment: I ran this program and [%d] prints an integer and %s prints a string. So is this an undefined behavior?

Comment: @KeithThompson I was wondering about that, that is one reasonable solution.

Comment: @Gopi: Yes, passing an argument whose type is inconsistent with the format string has undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson ,Shafik thank you both, the solution casting currentTime to long worked

Answer (score 1):

The below link might help you:

[What is ultimately a time_t typedef to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to)

Since the `time_t` doesn't specify any particular type or range this will lead to undefined behavior.

You also need to change your function name because compiler may throw below warning:

```
warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'log'
```