# Define Variables in C++ : datatype(value)

Tags: c++

I recently encountered a code that read

```
time_t zombieDate(0x510B56CB);
```

1) I know that time_t is a arithmetic variable type but what is its limit?

2) zombieDate is the name given to the variable but is the code above equivalent to:

```
time_t zombieDate = 0x510B56CB
```

Thanks!

Comment: `time_t` is implementation defined, but it must be able to hold at least the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  Look for the typedef in your system headers.  It may be in ctime or another header ctime includes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is ultimately a time\_t typedef to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to)

Comment: When I search online, I  got "Time type:
Alias of a fundamental arithmetic type capable of representing times, as those returned by function time." But I couldn't see how I should use it.

Comment: On my computer, it says:  typedef __time64_t time_t;  and typedef __int64 __time64_t;

Comment: @Retired Ninja  Sry, I still do not understand how the value is passed in.

Comment: Passed into what?  Both of those lines assign 0x510B56CB to a time_t variable named zombieDate.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that time_t is a arithmetic variable type but what is its limit?

It's implementation dependent. On POSIX systems, it must be at least 32 bits, to cover times up to at least the year 2038. You can get the limit for your implementation as you can for any numeric type:

```
std::numeric_limits<time_t>::max
```

> is the code above equivalent to...

Yes, if you add the missing `;` to the second declaration. For numeric types copy-initialisation and direct-initialisation both do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. Your reply is definitely very instructive.