# Converting a string of the form "##:##" to a time type, and then waiting for that time

Tags: c, windows, file, time

So, my work is made like this:

**order.txt**

> file.txt;5
>
> file2.txt;6
>
> file3.txt;7

In the code, it will open **file.txt**, list the content, wait **5** seconds, open **file2.txt**, list the content, wait **6** seconds, etc, etc.
As you may have seen already, the file.txt is the name of the file, and the number after is the time in seconds.

Yet, I need to do the following:

**order.txt**

> 15:00;file.txt;5
>
> 15:10;file2.txt;6
>
> 16:00;file3.txt;7

Which is supposed to list the content of file.txt at windows time **15:00** for **5** seconds ***(then I'll have an "default" file to show when none is there)*** and at **15:10** **file2.txt**, etc etc.

***To get the value of the first time is with the scanf which I'll probably have the following:***

```
while(fscanf(orderFile," %49[^;]; %49[^;];%d",time,fileName,&seconds) == 3)
```

How do I convert that **time** variable from a string to a time type?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Inside main:

**Variables:**

```
FILE* orderFile;
FILE* contentFile;
FILE* defaultFile;
char defaultContent[5000];
char fileName[50];
char textContent[5000];
int seconds;
int hour, min;
char timeValue[10];
time_t rawTime;
struct tm *currentTime;
```

**Code:**

```
orderFile = fopen("order.txt","r");

while(fscanf(orderFile," %49[^;]; %49[^;];%d",timeValue,fileName,&seconds) == 3)
{
    contentFile = fopen(fileName,"r");

    sscanf(timeValue,"%d:%d",&hour,&min);
    timeValue(&rawTime);
    currentTime = localtime(&rawTime);

    if(contentFile != NULL)
    {
       fseek (contentFile, 0, SEEK_END);
       size = ftell(contentFile);
       rewind(contentFile);
                    
       if(size == 0)
       {
           printf("\nEmpty file, make sure there's something to list inside. (Scanned file: %s)\n", fileName);
           fclose(contentFile);
       }
       else
       {
           if(currentTime->tm_hour == hour && currentTime->tm_min == min)
           {
               while(fscanf(contentFile,"%[^\t]",textContent) == 1)
               {
                   printf("%s\n", textContent); 
               }

               sleep(seconds);
           }  
           else
           {
                 while(fscanf(defaultFile,"%[^\t]",defaultContent) == 1)
                 {
                      printf("%s\n", defaultContent);
                 }
                        
                      difftime(time,currentTime);
                      sleep(difftime);
           }
                fclose(defaultFile);
                fclose(contentFile);
       }
    }
    else
    {
        if(contentFile == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nFile does not exist, please make sure the name is correct. (Scanned file: %s)\n", fileName);
        fclose(contentFile);
        }
    }
}
fclose(orderFile);
```

I translated the code and text to english so you would have a better understanding.

How do I, with the scanf I meantioned before, get the time in the txt file, convert it to a time type, and then list it only when windows time is the same?

Example:

**order.txt**

> 15:00;file.txt;5
>
> 15:10;file2.txt;6
>
> 16:00;file3.txt;7

It's **14:59**, **fileWhenThereAreNoFiles.txt content** will appear as a **default**.
At **15:00 windows time**, **file.txt** will open and list the content. After **5** seconds, **fileWhenThereAreNoFiles.txt content** will be back as **default**. At **15:10**, the same happens with **file2.txt**.

I have +/- of an idea which is check the time in the file, then check windows time, do one minus another, and if it's 0 then present it. But I don't know how to make a code for such a thing or how to convert string in time. How can I do that?

Comment: Suggest reading lines with `fgets()` and then use `sscanf()`.

Comment: `sscanf(time, "%d:%d", &hh, &mm);` should do it, shouldn't it?

Comment: Hm, got +/- that part, and how do I calculate that time with windows time? (I'm a windows user, for example at the moment is 00:18, how do I get that time, and then calculate it with the file time so I know when to list it?) Or something to make if(windowsTime == fileTime) then(list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to do it.

`#include <time.h>`

Variable declarations:

```
  int hour, min;
  time_t rawTime;
  struct tm *curTime;
```

Converting the read "hh:mm" string `time` to int `hour` and `min`:

```
  sscanf(time, "%d:%d", &hour, &min);
```

Getting the local_time:

```
  time(&rawTime);       
  curTime = localtime(&rawTime);
```

Using the read `tm` structure:

> ```
>   if(curTime->tm_hour == hour && curTime->tm_min == min) {
>     // display the given file's contents
>     // wait for `seconds` seconds
>
>     // display default file's contents 
>   }
> ```

**Additional info:** the`tm` structure has more fields than these two (`tm_hour` and `tm_min`). You might find it useful to have a look at the `tm` structure. The complete `tm` structure has following fields:

> `tm_sec`, seconds after the minute  (0-59), {(0-61) on some systems for leap seconds}
>      `tm_min`, minutes after the hour   (0-59)
>      `tm_hour`, hours since midnight     (0-23)
>      `tm_mday`, day of the month         (1-31)
>      `tm_mon`, months since January     (0-11)
>      `tm_year`, years since 1900
>      `tm_wday`, days since Sunday        (0-6)
>      `tm_yday`, days since January 1     (0-365)
>      `tm_isdst`, Daylight Saving Time flag

Comment: Hm thank you, got it. I know now +/- how it works. On the // display default file's contents is it safe to do it there? I mean, what if after that first content there's a second content to appear? 15:00 and 15:01 while the first appears for 60 seconds? Will it show default or? Should I do an if saying != hour && != min or should I calculate something such as difftime(time,curTime) or something?

Comment: @Ran, I added it there, because it seemed most logical to me. Suppose you first display the default file's contents and then enter a loop where you check for timing. Once you finish displaying the (new-file's) given text, you can just display the default-file's  contents. And keep on waiting inside the loop until the next condition gets satisfied. [But you don't have to do it my way, you can very well remove it.]

Comment: I'll have later to think exactly how the default will be displayed. Yet, it was a great help. Thank you.

Comment: May I just ask, what is the rawTime?

Comment: @Ran, See the variable declarations section above. `rawTime` is a `time_t` object.

Comment: @Ran, If you want more info on `time_t`, you may find this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to useful.

Comment: I meant what it actually means. By the way, I've tried it and it gives an error in time($rawTime); Called object 'time' is not a function or function pointer. I declared time as a char time[10], was it wrong on me doing that? I also have the sscanf after doing the fscanf, is it correct?

Comment: @Ran, it's `&` not `$`.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I typed wrong in here. I'll update my topic with the code I have, there is a & aswelll.

Comment: @Ran, since `time()` is a library function (already defined) in `<time.h>`. New variables or functions with the same name should not be defined. Change your variable name to something else.

Comment: @Ran, from the error you are telling, most probably you haven't included `time.h` (or because of the name conflict). See the very top of my answer.

Comment: Changed it to "timeFile" and still doesn't work. Is it because I declared as a char[10]?

Comment: I have both. Changed to testValue and does not work as well. I updated my code with that there is in it.

Comment: @Ran, can't say unless I see the whole program.

Comment: I updated with the whole variables for that case (which is my case 4:) and the includes.

Comment: @Ran can you share your code in pastebin or something. I really need to see what's causing the problem.

Comment: Sure I'll translate it there and do it.

Comment: Ehm, I think I've found it. I thought that at time(&rawTime), the time was my variable. No more errors, will now try it now thought.

Comment: Well no errors but still doesn't work, probably because of the sleep with difftime as idk how to use it. Any ideas?

Comment: I did now diff_time = difftime(currentTime,timeValue); but it only shows up one of the contents. Which in my case was default.

Comment: @Ran, Now you have come very close to your solution. There could be some minor bugs remaining. But I am very sure that you can now finish it on your own.