# Simplest way to have the following timer

Tags: c++, boost, time.h

I am currently trying to re-write some software in C++ from an old python code.
In the python version I used to have timers like these:

```
from time import time, sleep

t_start = time()
while (time()-t_start < 5) # 5 second timer
    # do some stuff
    sleep(0.001) #Don't slam the CPU

sleep(1)
print time()-t_start # would print something like 6.123145 notice the precision!
```

However, in C++ when I try to use `time(0)` from `< time.h >` I can only get precision in seconds as an integer, not a float.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

time_t t_start = time(0)
while (time(0) - t_start < 5) // again a 5 second timer.
{
    // Do some stuff 
    sleep(0.001) // long boost sleep method.
}
sleep(1);
std::cout << time(0)-t_start; // Prints 6 instead of 6.123145
```

I have also tried `gettimeofday(struct, NULL)` from `< sys/time.h >` however whenever I sleep the program with `boost::this_thread::sleep` it doesn't count that time...

I hope somebody here has come across a similar problem and found a solution.

Also, I really do need the dt in at least millisecond precision, because in the

`// Do some stuff`

part of the code I may break out of the while loop early and I need to know how long I was inside, etc.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: You are not getting a floating point result, because time_t is integer type according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to

Answer (score 0):

**[`gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday)** is known to have issues when there are discontinuous jumps in the system time.

For portable milisecond precision have a look at **[`chrono::high_resolution_clock()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/)**

Here a little snippet:

```
chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point ts = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point te = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// ... do something ...
cout << "took " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(te - ts).count() << " millisecs\n";
```

*Please note the real clock resolution is bound to the operating system.  For instance, on windows you usually have a 15ms precision, and you can go beyond this constraint only by using platform dependent clocking systems.*

Comment: Is it possible to store the difference as a double??

Comment: needs to mention boost::chrono for Windows (I believe the MSVS2015 CTP might fix the resolution?).

Comment: @ch0l1n3 `c::duration_cast<c::milliseconds>(duration).count()/1000.0` e.g. (c=std::chrono)

Comment: so like this?
double dt = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(te - ts).count()/1000.0
Also, i'm using linux, so perhaps the resolution issue is different!

Comment: My understanding is that `chrono::high_resolution_clock` is not guaranteed to be 'steady' and not 'jump around'.