# Negative value returned by time

Tags: c++, time, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I try to return number of second from 1970 with time function with `stm32f4` card.

I have these datatype configured

```
RTC_HandleTypeDef RtcHandle;
RTC_DateTypeDef dateStruct;
RTC_TimeTypeDef timeStruct;
```

I do a call to

```
HAL_RTC_GetTime
HAL_RTC_GetDate
```

and i call this function

```
long SystemClock::getUnixTimestamp()
  struct tm timeinfo;

  //Setup a tm structure based on the RTC
  timeinfo.tm_wday = dateStruct.WeekDay;
  timeinfo.tm_mon = dateStruct.Month - 1;
  timeinfo.tm_mday = dateStruct.Date;
  timeinfo.tm_year = dateStruct.Year + 100;
  timeinfo.tm_hour = timeStruct.Hours;
  timeinfo.tm_min = timeStruct.Minutes;
  timeinfo.tm_sec = timeStruct.Seconds;

  time_t rawtime = mktime(&timeinfo);

  trace_printf("Current date and time are: %s\n", ctime(&rawtime));
  long x = time(&rawtime);
  trace_printf("time %lu\n", x);
  return x;
}
```

I see

```
Current date and time are: Wed Apr 29 22:46:00 2015
time 1430347560

5 second later, i do another call to HAL_RTC_GetTime, HAL_RTC_GetDate, getUnixTimestamp and i get

Current date and time are: Wed Apr 29 22:46:05 2015
time 1430347560
```

why time is not modified?

Comment: Please elaborate on "if I try to display". What code did you use to display `rawtime`?

Comment: The value `-1074790400` is suspicious; that's `0xbff00000` in hexadecimal. Assuming the usual 1970 epoch, the value returned by `time(NULL)` or `time(&rawtime)` should be something like `1430445026`. Please update  your question to show how you're printing it. Something like `printf("%ld\n", (long)time(NULL));` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
printf("time %d\n", time(&rawtime));
```

to display `rawtime`  is not appropriate. `time_t` is not necessarily an `int`.

Here's some code that I copied from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time to display the value returned by `time`:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result))
              << result << " seconds since the Epoch\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I am reading, it seems that `time()` may return a negative value : [What is ultimately a time_t typedef to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to)

> Unix and POSIX-compliant systems implement the time_t type as a
>   signed
>         integer (typically 32 or 64 bits wide) which represents the number of seconds since the start of the Unix epoch: midnight UTC of
>   January 1, 1970 (not counting leap seconds). Some systems correctly
>   handle negative time values, while others do not. Systems using a
>   32-bit time_t type are susceptible to the Year 2038 problem.

Functions in the `time.h` library will be able treat these negative values and translate them into actual dates. In fact, this can be proven on your computer since `ctime()` works fine.

In your situation, if you absolutely need the number of seconds, you'll want to convert/typecast the return value of `time()` into a long before printing it out.

```
printf("Time : %lu", (long)time(&rawtime));
```

Comment: @roberttrudel Sorry, try %lu for unsigned long.

Comment: with lu, it's get something but i get something strange. i do a call  to get time, date, display value with: ctime(&rawtime), display value with your command. i do a sleep of 5 second. i see the change with ctime(&rawtime) but not with your command.

Comment: @roberttrudel Do not confuse ctime() with time(). Here is a snippet of code showing that this line works : http://ideone.com/So0JVP

Comment: @roberttrudel I undestand. I tried running my code with a sleep(5) in between and it is working : http://ideone.com/yqqX5m From this, your issue seems to be either the "x" variable is not being reassigned or the 5 second sleep is not working for you.