# portable way to get time

Tags: c, loops, timer

Since Mac OS X doesn't support get time, I found this gist that made a portable way to use the clock_gettime fund here:

```
void current_utc_time(struct timespec *ts) {

#ifdef __MACH__ // OS X does not have clock_gettime, use clock_get_time
    clock_serv_t cclock;
    mach_timespec_t mts;
    host_get_clock_service(mach_host_self(), CALENDAR_CLOCK, &cclock);
    clock_get_time(cclock, &mts);
    mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), cclock);
    ts->tv_sec = mts.tv_sec;
    ts->tv_nsec = mts.tv_nsec;
#else
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ts);
#endif
}
```

using it like this

```
struct timespec requestStart;
current_utc_time(&requestStart);
printf("start: s:  %lu\n", requestStart.tv_sec);
printf("start: ns: %lu\n", requestStart.tv_nsec);
start: s:  1435988139
start: ns: 202015000
```

I am trying to get the seconds and milliseconds value from this code, is this the correct way to get milliseconds from the nanoseconds value?

```
printf("total: ms:  %lu\n", (requestStart.tv_nsec - requestEnd.tv_nsec) / (unsigned long)1000000);
```

If so, how do I get the seconds value? If not how can I get the milliseconds and seconds value?

**edit**
In response to the first comment, I am mainly looking for a way to have the code as portable as possible.

Comment: This is _so_ not ANSI C :-) In any case, the real standard is ISO, ANSI is just one of the feeder bodies into that nowadays.

Comment: MacOS doesn't have a simple interface for getting the system time?  That's pretty hard to believe!

Comment: @wallyk as you can see from apples official docs I used the timer they provide in the function above. Here's the doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2169/_index.html I was more concerned about converting the nanoseconds to seconds and milliseconds from the above function.

Comment: did you try to link with `-lrt`?  **clock_gettime(3)** is a POSIX compliant function but in several architectures you have to link it or use the `#define _POSIX_SOURCE` macro to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want portability, just use `gettimeofday`.  That should work everywhere.  `clock_gettime` appears to be <s>Linux-specific</s> a relatively recent Posix introduction.

On converting: `struct timeval` (used by `gettimeofday` and other older functions) uses microseconds.  The newer `struct timespec` uses nanoseconds.  So to convert back and forth, you would multiply or divide by 1000.

When computing differences, you have to worry about carry/overflow, so your expression

```
(requestStart.tv_nsec - requestEnd.tv_nsec) / (unsigned long)1000000
```

is incorrect for two reasons: the difference might come out negative (that is, if the time went from 123.456 to 124.321), and you're scaling it by too much.

When I'm timing some operation, I usually do it something like this:

```
struct timeval before, after, elapsed;
gettimeofday(&before, NULL);
sleep(1);
gettimeofday(&after, NULL);
elapsed.tv_sec = after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec;
if(after.tv_usec >= before.tv_usec)
        elapsed.tv_usec = after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec;
else    {
        elapsed.tv_sec--;
        elapsed.tv_usec = 1000000 + after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec;
        }
printf("elapsed: %d.%06ld\n", (int)elapsed.tv_sec, (long)elapsed.tv_usec);
```

If I then wanted a `struct timespec` (using nanoseconds), I'd multiply by 1000:

```
struct timespec elapsed2;
elapsed2.tv_sec = elapsed.tv_sec;
elapsed2.tv_nsec = elapsed.tv_usec * 1000;
printf("elapsed: %d.%09ld\n", (int)elapsed2.tv_sec, (long)elapsed2.tv_nsec);
```

To convert from a `struct timespec` back to a `struct timeval`, I'd divide by 1000:

```
struct timeval elapsed3;
elapsed3.tv_sec = elapsed2.tv_sec;
elapsed3.tv_usec = elapsed2.tv_nsec / 1000;
```

Another useful thing is to pull out seconds and subseconds as floating point:

```
double e = (double)elapsed.tv_sec + elapsed.tv_usec / 1e6;
double e2 = (double)elapsed2.tv_sec + elapsed2.tv_nsec / 1e9;
printf("float: %f %f\n", e, e2);
```

(It turns out that there can be subtleties when writing this sort of code, depending on the actual types of `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` or `tv_nsec`, and on the "helpful" warnings your compiler might choose to give you.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157164/why-c-has-so-many-different-types).)

Comment: This is the most detailed answer I've seen and it's helped me so much. So you can convert from these different time structures.

Comment: Minor: `printf("elapsed: %d.%09ld\n", (int)elapsed2.tv_sec, (long)elapsed2.tv_nsec);`  `(long)` cast not needed as field `tv_nsec`is specified as `long`.  Casting field `time_t tv_sec` to `int` can easily be a narrowing: Consider `"%lld", (long long) elapsed2.tv_sec` to avoid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <time.h>
#import <sys/timeb.h>

struct timeb timebCurrentTime;

ftime(&timebCurrentTime);
double y = (double)timebCurrentTime.time + (double)timebCurrentTime.millitm / 1000;//current time in sec since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)
```

Comment: 1) Can you add a little bit of explanation? and 2) I think you meant `#include` there, not `#import`