# c timeval vs timespec

Tags: c, linux, time

Apart from the difference of precision, what are the differences between `struct timeval` and `struct timespec`? If I need less precision than µs (say, milliseconds), why would I use one over the other?

On my compiler (gcc for ARM):

```
/* POSIX.1b structure for a time value.  This is like a `struct timeval' but
   has nanoseconds instead of microseconds.  */
struct timespec
  {
    __time_t tv_sec;        /* Seconds.  */
    __syscall_slong_t tv_nsec;  /* Nanoseconds.  */
  };

/* A time value that is accurate to the nearest
   microsecond but also has a range of years.  */
struct timeval
  {
    __time_t tv_sec;        /* Seconds.  */
    __suseconds_t tv_usec;  /* Microseconds.  */
  };
```

With both `__syscall_slong_t` and `__suseconds_t` defined as a "long word".

Comment: You use the correct structure for the system calls you're going to use — `struct timeval` for `gettimeofday()` (and `select()`), and `struct timespec` for `clock_gettime()`. For internal processing, you can use either or both, as is convenient for you. Conversion between the two is relatively painless; input and output requires a modicum of care (mainly making sure leading zeros for the fractional part are printed and scanned correctly when necessary).  BSD and Mac OS X provide some primitive arithmetic and comparison facilities for `struct timeval`; there is no analogue for `struct timespec`.

Comment: You should look at [Why C has so many different types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157164/) which is also asking about `struct timeval`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think it's really just a matter of API [in]compatibility. POSIX-y calls like [`pselect()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pselect.html) and [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) use `struct timespec`. Various filesystem calls like [`utimes()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimes.html), and some assorted Linux calls like [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) and [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html), use `struct timeval`. Broadly generalizing from a few man pages, I suspect that `struct timeval` has a BSD legacy whereas `struct timespec` is POSIX.

If you're doing interval measurements, there's no reason not to leverage the extra precision from `clock_gettime()` — though beware that it's usually hardware, not the header file, that limits your measuring precision. Dividing by a million for display purposes is hardly better or worse than dividing by a thousand.  (Also, [Mac OS X prior to 10.12 did not support `clock_gettime()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x).)

But if you're doing lots of file time manipulation, it might make more sense to use the `struct timeval` used in APIs like `utimes()`. `struct timeval` also has some comparison functions on Linux, BSD and Mac OS X, e.g. `timercmp()`, `timersub()` (again, see man pages).

I'd make the decision based on the APIs you intend to use, rather than on the structures themselves. (Or write a wrapper class with conversion methods if necessary.)

Comment: My current version of Mac OS X (10.12) does support `clock_gettime`.

Comment: @ioquatix `clock_gettime()` has been added in 10.12, before that version you could use `mach_time` to get a high precision, monotonic clock.

Answer (score 3):

Both are AFAIK defined for POSIX.1-2001, so from a portability point of view, it doesn't matter which one you use. The most simple answer is: use whichever you need for the API you intend to call.

There COULD be a platform-dependent size benefit using `struct timeval`:

> The  type  suseconds_t  shall  be  a signed integer type
>   capable of storing values at least in the range [-1, 1000000].

in `struct timespec` the second member is of type `long`. An `int` would be enough on a 32bit platform to fulfill the `suseconds_t` requirements. But, on a 64bit system, `time_t` is typically 64 bit, thus forcing the structure to pad to 16 bytes anyway. So a size benefit is -- improbable.

Comment: Yes, both are still POSIX but since POSIX.1-2008+TC1 some functions that use `struct timeval` are marked as obsolescent. `struct timespec` is also part of the ISO C standard since C11.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use neither one. I prefer to express time as a simple `int64_t` because that makes time calculations dead simple and if you have to, converting back to `struct timeval` or `struct timespec` is no problem either. Even if you want a precision of nanoseconds, `int64_t` can express a span of almost 585 years. If you just need milliseconds, you have a span of almost 585 million years.

Comment: Only problem is time_t is not specified by the standard as being signed OR unsigned or integral OR floating point. And it doesn't specify a MAX limit either.  So conversion is actually a pain