# boost timed_wait doesn't wait if date is in 2116 year

Tags: c++, linux, boost

The example:

```
boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore semDone(0);
long sec = 10;
boost::posix_time::ptime until = boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time() + boost::posix_time::seconds(sec);
bool ret = semDone.timed_wait(until);
```

It works perfectly on Linux at the time - the `timed_wait` waits for 10 seconds and then returns `false`.

However if I move the system date to **2116** year and re-run the app, the `timed_wait` call returns `false` immediately. There is the same problem with the boost's condition vars.

Could please anybody explain what's wrong with it?

Info:

- Linux sles12 3.12.39 **x86_64** GNU/Linux
- g++ 4.8
- boost 1.54

UPD As I already wrote above, I'm running the test on **64bit platform**, and the size of `time_t` equals 8. So the answers advising to use 64bit `time_t` instead of 32bit are not applicable for the question.

Comment: Is your timezone set to UTC?

Comment: @stark no, the time zone is EST

Comment: To summarize: 32-bit time_t doesn't have enough room for that many seconds. Use a 64-bit time_t.

Comment: @ZanLynx why do you think time_t is 32bit? I noted that I use x64 platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that `boost::posix_time::time_duration::total_seconds()` explicitly casts the return value to `time_resolution_traits::sec_type` while converting `ptime` to `timespec` via `boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::ptime_to_timespec()` during the `timed_wait()` call.
The `time_resolution_traits::sec_type` is a typedef to **`int32_t`** type (see the typedef chain in *boost/date_time/time_resolution_traits.hpp* file).

At the same time documentation says that `time_duration::total_seconds()` returns **`long`** (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html). But for **LP64** models (e.g. Linux, 64bit) it returns signed 32bit integer, not `long` (signed 64bit integer).

So obviously **there is a bug in boost**. The first ticket for the bug was created in 2009. And it is still not fixed.

The tickets:

- https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2819
- https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3109
- https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3487
- https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12214

  I created the new  one: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12609.

---

**UPD**: The **bug was fixed in Boost 1.66** as it's described at the bug's comments.

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to describe what happens with a small stacktrace to the line where the problem occurs (btw, I am using boost 1.58):

```
#0  boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::ptime_to_timespec (tm=...) at /usr/include/boost/interprocess/sync/posix/ptime_to_timespec.hpp:38
#1  0x402983 in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::semaphore_timed_wait (handle=0x7fffffffe100, abs_time=...) at /usr/include/boost/interprocess/sync/posix/semaphore_wrapper.hpp:224
#2  0x402ab7 in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::posix_semaphore::timed_wait (this=0x7fffffffe100, abs_time=...) at /usr/include/boost/interprocess/sync/posix/semaphore.hpp:55
#3  0x402b1d in boost::interprocess::interprocess_semaphore::timed_wait (this=0x7fffffffe100, abs_time=...) at /usr/include/boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_semaphore.hpp:139
#4  0x40184d in main () at /tmp/t.cpp:10
```

Ok, so lets have a look what happens in the method ptime_to_timespec.
Your previously created ptime object (line 3)

```
boost::posix_time::ptime until = boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time() + boost::posix_time::seconds(sec);
```

is passed to this function and is converted into a timespec object. The timespec object is defined in **time.h** and can be used to compute the duration since 00:00:00 January 1, 1970. (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html) It contains members like **tv_sec** (duration in seconds, type time_t), **tv_nsec** (type long), etc.

The problem simply is that the duration in seconds (starting at 01/01/1970 and ending at XX/XX/2116) is too large and does not fit into **tv_sec** (time_t is basically a signed int). The problem is also described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/471287/5967798

I tested it with year 2116 and the timespec that was returned by the function described the date 
`9:18:59 am CET | Wednesday, October 8, 1980`

Comment: Is there a workaround?  Like using an alternate way to build `until` ?

Comment: When I build a 64-bit binary, time_t is 8 bytes.

Comment: Yes, I just double checked and saw that the described problem is not the only bad thing here. After a little bit of debugging it seems that the method boost::posix_time::time_duration::total_seconds()

Comment: Checked again and saw that following call `boost::posix_time::time_duration::total_seconds()` returns an int with 4 bytes. and this is not enough.

Comment: @stefanmoosbrugger so it looks like your answer is not correct - the problem is in boost library, not in timespec or time_t, right?

Comment: Well, on a 32 bit system it is right.. In the case of 32-bit both boost and timespec will fail. In the case of 64-bit only boost will provide a wrong result. I checked the return type of the `boost::posix_time::time_duration::total_seconds()` on a 64-bit system and it is a 4 byte signed int.

Comment: @stefanmoosbrugger the original question was about 64bit platform.