# How to measure time intervals?

Tags: c

I have a model of a neuron firing. There are many variables in c code, but the one I am interested in is voltage. I want to keep track of how long the neuron fires and once the neuron reaches a certain value (here -20 mV) it will definitely fire. I've attached a picture - I want to keep track of the green parts especially. I'm guessing you use the time fxn but I'm not sure how?
[image]

x[i] represents voltage. This is the equation for dx[i]

```
 dx[i]=ab*(-(ina(frt,v[i],n[i],nae[i],nai[i])+inap(frt,v[i],hp[i],nae[i],nai[i])+ik(frt,v[i],n[i],ke[i],ki[i])+ipump[i]+il(v[i])+inmda(inanmda,iknmda,icanmda)+icapump)+iapp); //v
```

Comment: As I am not into "*firing neurons*" ;-): would a resolution in seconds do?

Comment: Yes seconds is good. - I need to find the time difference when the neuron voltage first increases and reaches -20 mV and then eventually it decreases and reaches -20 mV

Comment: The question seems ambiguous to me. Do you want to *"measure the time a part of your code runs for"* or *"compute time using physical formulas"*?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int t1 = time(0);
fire_neuron();     // place the "neuron firing" code here
int t2 = time(0);

printf("Seconds taken to fire neuron: %d\n", t2 - t1);
```

If you want to do it "properly", you can `#include <time.h>` and write it like this:

```
time_t t1 = time(NULL);
fire_neuron();            // place the "neuron firing" code here
time_t t2 = time(NULL);

printf("Seconds taken to fire neuron: %f\n", difftime(t2, t1));
```

As I can't see your code, I don't know exactly how to help you. Maybe you want something like...

```
if (dx[i] <= -20) {
    time_t t1 = time(NULL);
    fire_neuron();
    time_t t2 = time(NULL);
}

printf("Seconds taken to fire neuron: %f\n", difftime(t2, t1));
```

Comment: `int` should really be `time_t`.

Comment: And `...  %d\n", t2 - t1);` should be `... %f\n", difftime(t2, t1));`

Comment: @alk Yes, yes, but [technically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to), `time_t` is a `typedef` for `signed int`.

Comment: how do i write in terms of the time interval being when the voltage first reaches -20 and then when it goes down to -20 ?

Comment: @soscrewed I have no idea; you'd need to show us your code. But first, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve).

Comment: @MDXF: Since around the year 2000, on many system it's a `long`, will say wider then 32 bits.

Comment: @soscrewed you have provided no code to indicate how you are going to get those values, so how are we supposed to know?

Comment: Sorry I would post the whole code but its too long. x[i] represents the voltage of the neuron, dx[i] is the rate of change of voltage                                                             dx[i]=ab*(-(ina(frt,v[i],n[i],nae[i],nai[i])+inap(frt,v[i],hp[i],nae[i],nai[i])+ik(frt,v[i],n[i],ke[i],ki[i])+ipump[i]+il(v[i])+inmda(inanmda,iknmda,icanmda)+icapump)+iapp); //v