# How to store time in 32bit width on 64bit system?

Tags: c

I have a structure like below:

```
typedef struct  ERROR_LOG_EVENT
{
    time_t time;
    uint32_t count;
    int32_t error_type;
} ERROR_LOG_EVENT;
```

I am storing this structure on a non-volatile memory.
On 32-bit system, everything works fine as `time_t` is 4 bytes(32bit) in width.

But on 64-bit system `time_t` becomes 8bytes(64bit) wide.

Is there a way to store time in `4byte(32bit)` on 64bit system?
Can I replace `time_t time`  member of the above structure with something that always is guaranteed to be 32-bit ?

Comment: I want `4 byte(32bit)` member representing `time`

Comment: Yes you can, but only if you don't think your program will be used beyond the year 2106 (if using e.g. `uint32_t`). ***And*** `time_t` is actually an integer counting the number of seconds since 1970-01-01. (If the epoch is earlier then the end date will of course be sooner too.)

Comment: What is the issue with having a 64 bit `time_t`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am fine with that assumption. Currently, the project works fine on 32-bit system. We are in a phase to port to 64-bit system, but don't want to increase memory for structures that are stored on non-volatile memory. Precision of time should work fine in both the cases

Comment: One problem with using `uint32_t` on a system where `time_t` is a 64-bit type, is that you need to explicitly cast assignments to your `time` member variable. Unless you like the compiler giving you warnings about loosing precision or something similar. And there will be some issues if `time_t` is a *signed* 64 bit integer (sign-extension etc).

Comment: If you are into saving memory space, you would need to deal with padding/alignment for your struct with int32 on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think the issue is not 2106 but sooner: [2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)  if we go with signed `time_t`.   _Only_ 21 years away.

Comment: This discussion provides some nice background on time_t.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/471287/6693299

Since time_t is guaranteed to represent the number of ticks since 1970 in either the 32 or 64 bit version, it is safe to take the least significant 32 bits and just store that. It is good to 2038 according to this link, not 2106.

Comment: @chux For a *signed* 32-bit time yes.

Comment: @chux let's assume that he would cast the time_t to an uint32, not int32

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Agreed with uint32_t, could go to 2106, yet my mis-reading of your comment is an example of the pitfalls of signed _signed_ time.

Comment: @ScottK "Since time_t is guaranteed to represent the number of ticks since 1970 in either the 32 or 64 bit version"  --> That guarantee is not in the C spec.

Comment: 1) You are not allowed to change standard headers. 2) That's an XY problem. **Why** do you want a 32 bit time representation? What is your problem using the correct type? 3) You call for another Y2K problem. Some people learned from it, thus now use a longer type. Why do you want to repeat that nonsense? If you have a storage issue, use a compressed storage format.

Comment: Does `int32_t error_type;` need 32-bits?

Comment: @chux yes it does. I would like to have 32-bit time representation on 64-bit machine and not changing other members. Since precision is not a problem here, I believe I can go with `uint32_t`

Comment: A common hack is to offset the `time_t` based on a more recent epoch, maybe 2107 JAn 1

Comment: @chux Thanks for the correction. I believe that this guarantee is only for POSIX compliant systems. Is that your understanding? Curious if you know of any popular systems that do not follow this convention regarding time_t representing the number of ticks?

Comment: one curious question. if its measurement of clock since 1970, why is it signed data type then ? in what case would we be requiring negative values ?

Comment: @Monku 1)  The error return from various time functions is C specified to be  `((time_t) -1)` , so there is at least one "negative" value.  2) The origins of `time_t` hearken to a time when `int` was very popular and some signed integer type has become common practice.

Comment: Hmm, on a 64-bit system, might the structure `ERROR_LOG_EVENT` tend to a 64-bit alignment and then the 32-bit savings are moot?

Comment: @ScottK I have worked on niched implementations that did not use Jan 1, 1970 integer seconds epoch.  Still portable code does not need to know the underlying implementation and so I often don't care much either.  I find timezones and DST more of a headache.

Comment: @Monku I suggest staying with `typedef struct  ERROR_LOG_EVENT
{
    time_t time;
    uint32_t count;
    int32_t error_type;
} ERROR_LOG_EVENT;`

Comment: @chux I can pack the structure to use 4-byte alignment.

Answer (score 1):

If memory space optimization if your goal (at the expense of slower access, and time limited to 2106), then you should define your struct as `packed` to suppress padding:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) ERROR_LOG_EVENT {
    uint32_t time;
    uint32_t count;
    int32_t error_type;
} ERROR_LOG_EVENT;
```

Then assign it like that:
`ERROR_LOG_EVENT.time = <time_t> & 0xFFFFFFFF;`

Comment: why do i need `packing` here ? I believe the `stricter alignment` is 4byte for this structure. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It depends on the compiler you use and the compilation options you use...

Answer (score 0):

Adapt your code to properly handle a 64-bit timestamp. Specifically, write something that looks like

```
typedef struct  ERROR_LOG_EVENT
{
    int64_t time;
    uint32_t count;
    int32_t error_type;
} ERROR_LOG_EVENT;
```

And force your 32-bit code to use this code. Don't try to store time intervals using 32-bit integers. That's always going to be a bad idea, and that's before you hit the problem of "oh, the design requirements changed, we actually want to save nanoseconds, not seconds".

Answer (score -1):

Use `uint32_t`. If these are unix epoch times, this will be sufficient for storing timestamps that are no [further](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) than the year 2105.