# Adding a few seconds of offset to stat()

Tags: c, time, offset, stat, strftime

I am using stat to get the last modified time of a file, but I would like to add a few seconds to the overall time.

```
if (stat(file_path, &st) == 0)
{
    char estimate_time[50];
    strftime(estimate_time, 50, "\'%F %T\'", localtime(&st.st_mtime)
}
```

So, this code works fine in getting the last modified time of the file, but I would just like to add a few seconds to the overall time. Is there a way to get "st_mtime" in seconds so I can simply add to that value and then use strftime to convert into a formatted output?

Thanks

Comment: `st_mtime` is already in seconds.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to

Comment: Are you trying to report a different mtime (modification time) for a file, or do you want to set/change the modification time?

Answer (score 1):

To portable add a few seconds to a `struct tm`, simple add to the `tm_sec` member and call `mktime()` to normalize the structure.

```
  struct stat st;
  struct tm *tm = localtime(&st.st_mtime);
  if (tm == NULL) Handle_Error();
  tm->tm_sec += offset;
  time_t time_new = mktime(tm);  // adjust fields.
  if (time_new == (time_t) -1) Handle_Error();
  strftime(estimate_time, sizeof estimate_time, "\'%F %T\'", tm);
```

Per the `[stat]` tag, OP is on a POSIX system which requires `time_t` is in seconds, so POSIX code may add to `st.st_mtime`.

```
  time_t new_time = st.st_mtime + offset;
  struct tm *tm = localtime(&new_time);
  if (tm == NULL) Handle_Error();
  strftime(estimate_time, sizeof estimate_time, "\'%F %T\'", tm);
```

Comment: POSIX requires that `time_t` be in seconds, so why wouldn't you be confident?

Comment: `&st.st_mtime + offset` is incorrect. You are adding to its address, not its value.

Comment: @Barmar OP's post is likely POSIX compliant, but that was not stated nor tagged as such.  Had it been, I would have answered that way.

Comment: @chux He's using the `stat()` function -- that implies it's POSIX.

Comment: @Barmar A reasonable conclusion, yet only an implication - even if a good one.  Other platforms may use `stat()` in a non-POSIX fashion.

Comment: The tag `stat` says "The stat(2) system call on POSIX systems". So he DID indirectly tag it POSIX.