# Precise time in nano seconds for Python 3.6 and earlier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I have been using a hack like this in a lot of my code:

```py
import time
if not hasattr(time, 'time_ns'):
    time.time_ns = lambda: int(time.time() * 1e9)
```

It works around the limitation of Python 3.6 and earlier, which did not have a `time_ns` method. The issue is that the above workaround is based on `time.time`, which returns a float. In 2019's UTC, this is about accurate to a micro-second scale.

How would I implement `time_ns` for older versions of Python with *full* nano-second accuracy? (Primarily targeting UNIX-like systems.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8709490f48fc27b3dd1a16acb33bea2299c6a575/Python/pytime.c#L695), the following can be derived:

```py
import ctypes

CLOCK_REALTIME = 0

class timespec(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('tv_sec', ctypes.c_int64), # seconds, https://stackoverflow.com/q/471248/1672565
        ('tv_nsec', ctypes.c_int64), # nanoseconds
        ]

clock_gettime = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6').clock_gettime
clock_gettime.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int64, ctypes.POINTER(timespec)]
clock_gettime.restype = ctypes.c_int64    

def time_ns():
    tmp = timespec()
    ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ctypes.pointer(tmp))
    if bool(ret):
        raise OSError()
    return tmp.tv_sec * 10 ** 9 + tmp.tv_nsec
```

The above works on 64bit UNIX-like systems.