# how to reverse the Bit operation in C

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

I have the following C program which will get the MSB, 2nd MSB, 3rd MSB and LSB for value now 1588800373). How do I reverse it? 
That is, If the program has time_0 = 94, time_1 = 179, time_2 = 43, time_3 = 117, how do I construct it back to now = 1588800373;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  time_t now = 1588800373; //time(NULL);
  uint8_t time_0 = now >> 24;
  uint8_t time_1 = (now >> 16) & 0xFF;
  uint8_t time_2 = (now >> 8) & 0xFF;
  uint8_t time_3 = now & 0xFF;

  printf("%lu, %u, %u, %u, %u\n", now, time_0, time_1, time_2, time_3);
  // 1588800373, 94, 179, 43, 117

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shift left and `OR`... Mind the types though.

Comment: Could you provide an example as shown in my program.

Comment: Just add this after your `printf` statement: `time_t then = (time_0 << 24) | (time_1 << 16) |  (time_2 << 8) | time_3; printf("%lu",then);`

Comment: @RamblinRose: That has problems with the types.

Comment: OK thanks - Additionally I found this SO post helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-time-t-ultimately-a-typedef-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift the bytes with at least 32-bit unsigned math and then `|`.

```
uint32_t repacked = ((uint32_t)time_0 << 24) | ((uint32_t)time_1 << 16) | 
    ((uint32_t)time_2 << 8) | time_3;
time_t now_again = (time_t) repacked;
```

---

`time_0 << 24` by itself converts `time_0` into an `int` and then shifts.  This has the potential to shift into the sign bit of an `int` and is *undefined behavior*.    On small platforms  with 16-int, is it also UB to shift 16 or more.  Use a wide enough unsigned type.

---

Original code is subject to the [y2038 bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) should `time_t` encode as a 32-bit signed `int`.  Better to first take `time_t` into a `uint32_t` and then split/shift into 4 bytes.