# Read Date Time in C++ Code from parquet files

Tags: c++, parquet, arrow-functions

I am reading a parquet file in a c++ program on windows platform.
The .parquet file has a column as "`timestamp`" and the data is like "`2021-04-06 16:48:04.614365+00:00`".
Presently I use `int64_t` as datatype to read the timestamp and it reads the time stamp as "`1671205687722819000`"

To read an integer I use code

```
std::shared_ptr<parquet::RowGroupReader> row_group_1 =  demoObj->myParquetReader->RowGroup(0);
std::shared_ptr<parquet::ColumnReader> colVal = row_group_1->Column(4);
parquet::Int64Reader* readerVal = static_cast<parquet::Int64Reader*>(colVal.get());
int ReadVal;
rowsRead = readerVal->**ReadBatch**(1, null, null, &ReadVal, &valRead);
```

How do I read the date time?

Comment: You could try converting it to a time_t and see if you get any useful output. Granted, time_t isn't gauranteed to be 64-bit (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-time-t-ultimately-a-typedef-to). If you have this, then you should just be able to manipulate it in your code using C/C++ time libraries.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I will check that. If there is any datatype/function provided by parquet then it will be faster conversion.

Comment: Looks like time is stored in microseconds, so divide by 1'000'000 to get an epoch timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of `timestamp` columns varies according to type parameters. From [the documentation](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#timestamp):

> The TIMESTAMP type has two type parameters:
>
> - `isAdjustedToUTC` must be either true or false.
> - `unit` must be one of `MILLIS`, `MICROS` or `NANOS`. This list is subject to potential expansion in the future. Upon reading, unknown unit-s must be handled as unsupported features (rather than as errors in the data files).

These parameters should be present in the `LogicalType` metadata, with a backwards-compatible definition in `ConvertedType` metadata.

From your post it looks like this file stored data in microseconds, so you can divide by 1'000'000 to get a unix epoch. But to know whether it is UTC-adjusted or not you need to query the metadata anyway, so do it right from the start and make your code handle the types according to the metadata.