# search for uses of int used instead of time_t

Tags: c, std, time-t

I have a rather large c-code base, where every once in a while int is used instead of time_t. Any good ideas as to how to deal with this. Should I search the entire standard library for functions that either return time_t or take it as argument, or is there a smarter way?

As I understand it, time_t will be 64 bit on a 64-bit system, at least on my system, which is 64 bit. An int will only be 32 bit on a 64-bit system. Which means that such an int will run out in 2038 if used as time_t.

Comment: [Unix and POSIX-compliant systems implement the time_t type as a signed
  integer (typically 32 or 64 bits wide) which represents the number of seconds since the start of the Unix epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-time-t-ultimately-a-typedef-to#:~:text=Unix%20and%20POSIX%2Dcompliant%20systems%20implement%20the%20time_t%20type%20as%20a%20signed%0A%20%20integer%20(typically%2032%20or%2064%20bits%20wide)%20which%20represents%20the%20number%20of%20seconds%20since%20the%20start%20of%20the%20Unix%20epoch)

Comment: Can you put more input in your question (seeing my previous comment) ? Maybe an example of a piece of code where it is obvious that you need to find this usage?

Comment: Yes. As I understand it, time_t will be 64 bit on a 64-bit system, at least on my system, which is 64 bit. An int will only be 32 bit on a 64-bit system. Which means that such an int will run out in 2038 if used as time_t.

Comment: Ok, so you are 14 years ahead of planning this change! Cool..., 

Comment: Exactly. If I have to do it manually, I fear that 14 years might not be enough.

Comment: I haven't used it but there is clang-query that might be interesting.

Comment: `rg time_t /usr/include` doesn't look scary.

Comment: Can you dig anything interesting out of debug information of your targets?

Comment: Which compiler / version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using gcc or clang, if you compile with the `-Wconversion` flag, it will warn you about converting from a larger type to a smaller type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    int i = t;

    printf("i=%d, t=%ld\n", i, t);

    return 0;
}
```

```
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -o x1 x1.c
x1.c: In function ‘main’:
x1.c:7:5: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘time_t’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     int i = t;
     ^
```

Comment: Microsofts C/C++ compiler will issue an `warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'time_t' to 'int', possible loss of data`  when using `/W3`  or `/W4`  (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-levels-3-and-4-c4244?view=msvc-170))

Comment: @Luuk It also uses a 32 bit `time_t`, so not really applicable here.

Comment: It default to 64bits, (according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64?view=msvc-170#:~:text=time%20is%20a,64%2Dbit%20platforms.))

Comment: @Luuk Ah, I was thinking of `struct timeval` which uses `long` for the fields instead of `time_t`.

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you mention, (64-bit system, 32-bit integer) enabling compiler warnings, or use of a good static analysis program should highlight all the cases of implicit narrowing conversion of a 64-bit (time_t) integer to a 32-bit integer.

If you are using MISRA C:2012/2023, Rule 10.3 also applies...

So (for example):

```
time_t        nowTime1 = clock(); /* OK                            */
int           nowTime2 = clock(); /* Implicit narrowing to 32 bits */
unsigned int  nowTime3 = clock(); /* Implicit narrowing to 32 bits */
uint32_t      nowTime4 = clock(); /* Implicit narrowing to 32 bits */
```

However:

```
uint64_t      nowTime5 = clock(); /* Probably OK */
unsigned long nowTime6 = clock(); /* Probably OK */
```

See also `time()` and `mktime()`, as well as `clock()`.

Assuming all your sources are the correct size, then any sinks (`ctime()`, `difftime()` etc) should be OK...