# Is Python's ctypes.c_long 64 bit on 64 bit systems?

Tags: python, 64-bit, ctypes

In C, long is 64 bit on a 64 bit system. Is this reflected in Python's [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_long) module?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The size of `long` [depends on the memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models). On Windows (LLP64) it is 32-bit, on UNIX (LP64) it is 64-bit.

If you need a 64-bit integer, use [`c_int64`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_int64).

If you need a pointer-sized integer, use [`c_void_p`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_void_p) (“The value is represented as integer”).

Comment: Oh wow, fantastic link, I never knew the memory model was formalized.

Answer (score 4):

Actually no.

On a Windows 64-bit system, long is 32 bits.

```
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79149, Mar 20 2010, 22:55:39) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.c_long(2**31)
c_long(-2147483648)
>>> ctypes.c_long(2**31+1)
c_long(-2147483647)
>>> ctypes.c_long(2**31-1)
c_long(2147483647)
>>>
```

See [What is the bit size of long on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows)

Comment: Nice work stomping out my assumption that Windows-64x was 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

If a C `long` is 64-bit (like it is on LP64 and ILP64 systems, pretty much any 64-bit system other than Windows), then so is `ctypes.c_long`. If a C long isn't 64-bit (like on LLP64 systems such as 64-bit Windows) then a `ctypes.c_long` isn't, either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
>>> ctypes.c_long(2**50)
c_long(1125899906842624)
>>> ctypes.c_long(2**64)
c_long(0)
>>> ctypes.c_long(2**63)
c_long(-9223372036854775808)
```

Comment: I assume you're running this from an LP64 OS, but the other answers actually told me when and why :)