# Why is my ctypes long size 4 and not size 8 using 64 bit python?

Tags: python, ctypes, anaconda

Downstream of this I am getting an error `Python int too large to convert to C long`, which led me to suspect that somehow ctypes long was too small - size 4 and not 8.

I tested this and it was indeed the case.  Yet, I am using Python 2.7 64 bit (Anaconda).

```
import ctypes as C
import os
import platform
import numpy as np

print "Python Platform Architecture: ", platform.architecture()[0]
print "Size of ctypes long: ", (C.sizeof(C.c_long))
```

This is the output:

```
Python Platform Architecture:  64bit
Size of ctypes long:  4
```

Comment: maybe duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323778/is-pythons-ctypes-c-long-64-bit-on-64-bit-systems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `long` is only guaranteed to be at least 32 bits wide, so on some systems, `ctypes.c_long` is only 32 bits. In particular, I believe on 64-bit Windows, `ctypes.c_long` is only 32 bits wide. If it *must* be 64 bits wide, use `ctypes.c_int64` instead.

Comment: Microsoft VC++ [data type ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) are the same for 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.