# Python c_ulong type is 64 bits on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, long-integer

It seems that on macOS Python's `c_ulong` type is 64 bits, instead of the 32 bits that it would be on Windows. From what I've found in my google search, based on this post: [Is Python's ctypes.c_long 64 bit on 64 bit systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323778/is-pythons-ctypes-c-long-64-bit-on-64-bit-systems)

It looks like it's because of macOS's memory model. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Define fix. Do you mean you want it to be 32 bits instead? What's wrong with 64 bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like if you are writing C, if you know that you specifically need a 32 bit unsigned integer, you shouldn't use `c_ulong` but instead [`ctypes.c_uint32`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_uint32). This way you can ensure it will be 32 bits no matter the platform you are on.