# How to make MS Visual C++ use LP64 instead of LLP64

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, 64-bit, abi

I'd like to know if it's possible to make VC++ use `LP64` instead of `LLP64`, I know I could use another compiler such as GCC or Intel C++, but I'd like to use VC++ for various reasons.

There is no requirement for compatibility with Microsoft headers, etc, and I am already using LIBC as my runtime library.

Comment: Why?  If you need a 64-bit integer, just use `int64_t`.

Comment: Using that logic, there's no need for `long`, `long long` or `short` :|

Comment: If you require an integer type with a particular width, you should use the specific fixed-width integer type.  That's what these types are for.

Comment: As stated, that logic renders no legitimate use for `short`, `long` or `long long` and a plain `char` type. I'm simply asking how to tell VC++ to use `LP64` instead of `LLP64`. The opposite can be done with GCC using `-mlong32`.

Comment: You can't.  End of story.

Comment: you can use `int_fast64_t` or `int_least64_t` if you don't like fixed-width

Comment: Microsoft did it for the Win64 port of (now dead) "Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications" (= Interix), which is using the Visual C++ compiler albeit through a convoluted way of calling: the `c89` script calls an helper program, named `l2ll` on every source file before feeding them to the `cl` compiler. The tool itself is discussed in a few place on the web. Besides the obvious replacement of long keyword, it also amend(ed) the L suffix for constants... There is no documentation for it, and of course the source is not available.
So it is certainly possible; it just neither easy nor pretty.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes "You can't" is also an answer. Because it's not possible (allegedly for [backwards compatibility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050131-00/?p=36563)).

Use portable types instead (`#include <cstdint>`):

- `int8_t`  - a 8-bit integer
- `int16_t` - a 16-bit integer
- `int32_t` - a 32-bit integer
- `int64_t` - a 64-bit integer

---

P.S. As a possible workaround you could use Cygwin, which uses LP64 [even on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39207744/485343).

Answer (score -2):

you can try to use

```
\#define long long long
```

or

```
/Dname[= | # [{string | number}] ]
```

so try

```
/Dlong="long long"
```

but this could be dangerous

Comment: This will just break every system call and calls to other libraries, aside from being a really bad coding practice.  Don't do it.  Note that it will replace existing occurrences of "long long" with "long long long long".