# unsigned long and uint32_t?

Tags: c, sockets, unsigned-long-long-int, uint32-t

I'm studying socket programming and I learned `inet_addr` function. But I'm confused how can I handle `in_addr_t` type.

`inet_addr` function returns `in_addr_t` type which is `uint32_t`, then do I have to use `uint32_t` type variable to handle it?

In the book, example handles it as `unsigned long` type, but I don't understand why this way is used.

```
unsigned long conv_addr = inet_addr(addr1); // unsigned long == uint32_t?
```

Comment: "*In the book*" - what book?

Comment: I'd just declare the variable as `in_addr_t` because that's what the function returns.

Comment: It's just korean book which teaches socket programming

Comment: When you say the `in_addr_t` type is `uint32_t`, is there documentation saying that, or did you look through the source code (likely in some system or implementation header file) to see how `in_addr_t` is defined? If you got it from source code, that is not equivalent to an assertion that `in_addr_t` will necessarily be defined as `uint32_t` in other versions of the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use `uint32_t` to handle the value returned from `inet_addr`. You can use any type that can represent any value that might be returned or that you might use in a calculation. But why not use the `uint32_t` or the `in_addr_t` type?

Comment: Then `uint32_t`==`in_addr_t`==`unsigned int`?

Comment: @coder: You should not assume types are identical unless you have documentation asserting that they are. A release of software X version N might define type `foo` to be `uint32_t`, but release N+1 of the software might define type `foo` to be `unsigned long`. Additionally, the width of `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` vary from C implementation to C implementation. C guarantees that `unsigned long` is at least as wide as `uint32_t`, so using `unsigned long` to hold a `uint32_t` variable is safe. But why would you choose to use a possibly wider type without needing too?

Comment: @coder `unsigned int` is not guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits wide. `in_addr_t` is [defined as `uint32_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/netinet/in.h.html#tag_13_32), however.

Comment: @EricPostpischil @melpomene Ah... I got it, then `unsigned long` is for safety and `in_addr_t` is correct for this situation. right?

Answer (score 0):

You may use **long** type also for inet_addr() function since most of the architecture use 32 bits(4 bytes) for long type but it is not always applicable

Some architecture use **64 bits** for **long** type..
[LP64 convention use 64 bits for long type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607502/sizeoflong-in-64-bit-c)

But the size of **uint32_t** is always **32 bits** independent of convention the compiler is following.

If you are writing programs using MSVC, it uses 32 bits for long type.

For gcc, it depends on computer hardware and implementation of GCC.

It is safe to use unsigned long for assigning to the return type of inet_addr() when you are confident with long size is 32 bits.

**Recommended** to use **uint32_t**(aka unsigned 32 bit memory) for inet_addr(), so you don't need to care about the size of long type at all...

Comment: "For gcc too, it uses 32 bits for long." --> sure about that?

Comment: *since most of the architecture use 32 bits(4 bytes) for long type* [That's not true.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) That's true mostly for on just Windows.  Just about every other 64-bit architecture extant uses a 64-bit `long`.

Comment: gcc depends on system architecture.[Refer here](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Integer-variables.html). Since most of the systems are 64 bit architecture nowadays, gcc uses 64 bits for long but still depends on system architecture