# How to make SWIG use 64bit integer for intptr_t on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, 32bit-64bit, swig, intptr

I would like to use SWIG on Windows for building 64 bit applications. I have a class that has a pointer in it to a buffer, and because I would like to interface with a .NET class, the pointer is declared as `intptr_t`.

The problem is that the standard SWIG `stdint.i` assumes that `intptr_t` is either `int` (on 32 bit environment) or `long` (on 64 bit environment). While this is true on Unix, it is false on Windows. Does anyone have either similar experience or any ideas how to create a workaround for this?

I already set up the typemaps needed for the `intptr_t` => `IntPtr` conversion and it is working fine in 32 bit environment, but it truncates the pointer in 64 bit environment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I will answer my own question. It seems that this is a bug in SWIG on Windows, that it treats `long` as `int64` on 64-bit Windows, while in reality it is an `int32`. See more about this topic here:
[What is the bit size of long on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows)

The other problem with SWIG is that it differentiates 32 and 64 bit code, but the reason I used `intptr_t` was to avoid bitness issues, as by definition it gives an integer large enough to hold a pointer.

So what I did at the end was to write a script that I run after generating the wrapper to fix the type signatures from `int` to `intptr_t`. While this is not elegant, I already have to do this for other reasons for my Python and PHP wrappers.