# How do I iterate over large numbers in Python using range()?

Tags: python, loops, python-2.x, largenumber

I want to iterate a large number such as 600851475143 using the range() function in Python. But whenever I run the program it gives me an OverflowError.
I have used the following code -

```
um = long(raw_input())
for j in range(1,num):
....
```

I have tried it many times but it is not working!

Comment: What do you want to do with these numbers? You almost certainly want `xrange` instead of range

Comment: @Thomas The number is too big for `xrange`

Comment: You may want to try this:
[range too large][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816603/range-is-too-large-python

Hope it helps

Comment: *Hint*: If you think the solution involves `range(1, 600851475143)`, you might need a different solution. That's going to be rather painfully slow.

Answer (score 4):

Use `itertools.islice()` if your indices are long numbers:

```py
from itertools import islice, count
islice(count(start, step), (stop-start+step-1+2*(step<0))//step)
```

Python 3's `range()` can handle python longs as well.

Simplified to your case:

```
for j in islice(count(1), num - 1):
```

Comment: Can you then correct my code?

Answer (score 2):

Although `xrange` seems to achieve what you want, it can't handle numbers that large. You may need to use this recipe from [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

> CPython implementation detail: xrange() is intended to be simple and fast. Implementations may impose restrictions to achieve this. The C implementation of Python restricts all arguments to native C longs (“short” Python integers), and also requires that the number of elements fit in a native C long. If a larger range is needed, an alternate version can be crafted using the itertools module: `islice(count(start, step), (stop-start+step-1+2*(step<0))//step)`.

Comment: Ah, I'm using 64bit Python so I didn't notice

Comment: in python 3 you can use range, in python2 use xrange as advised http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range

Answer (score 1):

don't use for, use while

```
counter = long(1)
while counter < num:
    ...
```