# Python Code Fails

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code fails. throwing an exception and producing no output.

The constraints on the input are 1<=n<=1000, 1<=k<=n and s.length is equal to n. It is also guaranteed that the input is exactly as specified.

Also, the code works, when 1<=n<=20.

```
def conforms(k,s):
    k = k + 1
    if s.find("0" * k) == -1 and s.find("1" * k) == -1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def brute(n,k,s):
    min_val = n + 1
    min_str = ""
    desired = long(s,2)
    for i in range (2 ** n):
        xor = desired ^ i # gives number of bit changes
        i_rep = bin(i)[2:].zfill(n) # pad the binary representation with 0s - for conforms()
        one_count = bin(xor).count('1')
        if one_count < min_val and conforms(k, i_rep):
            min_val = bin(xor).count('1')
            min_str = i_rep

    return (min_val,min_str)

T = input()
for i in range(T):
    words = raw_input().split() 
    start = raw_input()
    sol = brute( int(words[0]), int(words[1]), start)
    print sol[0]
    print sol[1]
```

Comment: `The following code fails and returns with an NZEC.` This is not SPOJ. Please explain what NZEC is.

Comment: Are you expecting the first line of `conforms` to modify the value of `k` in `brute`? It won't.

Comment: You should at least provide the traceback of the exception.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I guess OP can not do that, because he submits the code to an online judge system which runs it against set of inputs

Comment: Specify the probable input for `T`,  `words`, `start`. It feels like you might pass a string of characters to the `int` function. And what is the reason to use the `input` function? Recall `input` = `eval(raw_input)`

Comment: T <=100 start is a binary string of length N

Comment: @xrisk and what about `words`?

Comment: words is a space-sepaarated string of two numbers

Comment: @xrisk post problem's text or link to its text at least.

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, I'm not expecting that.

Comment: @Alik http://www.codechef.com/MAY15/problems/DEVSTR/

Comment: And, err, sorry for the delay in replying. Wifi troubles.

Comment: You want to run `i` all the way up to `2**1000`, but it fails around `2**20`? I can't say I'm too surprised, since a string of length `2**20` already has over a million digits; but how about you include the traceback so we can see exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: @alexis - python has arbitrary length numbers, doesn't it?

Comment: @xrisk, it does, but if you try to execute `In [1]: range(2**(10**3))` you will get `OverflowError: range() result has too many items` and this seems to be the root of the problem

Comment: @Alik, any way to circumvent this?

Comment: @Alik never mind, I got what I wanted - why the code was failing. It was because of some language construct and not my algo itself. And this was the bruteforce solution anyway. I suggest you make it an answer.

Comment: @xrisk replace it with `while` loop. I think it will fail due to time limit though.

Comment: @Alik Of course it will.  2**1000 ~ 10e301 And the time limit is 1 second.   Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `range` and `xrange` are written in C, hence they are prone to overflows. You need to write your own number generator to surpass the limit of C `long`.

```
def my_range(end):
    start = 0
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start +=1 


def conforms(k,s):
    k = k + 1
    if s.find("0" * k) == -1 and s.find("1" * k) == -1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def brute(n,k,s):
    min_val = n + 1
    min_str = ""
    desired = long(s,2)
    for i in my_range(2 ** n):
        xor = desired ^ i # gives number of bit changes
        i_rep = bin(i)[2:].zfill(n) # pad the binary representation with 0s - for conforms()
        one_count = bin(xor).count('1')
        if one_count < min_val and conforms(k, i_rep):
            min_val = bin(xor).count('1')
            min_str = i_rep
    return (min_val,min_str)


T = 1
for i in range(T):
    words = [100, 1]
    start = '00000001'
    sol = brute(words[0], words[1], start)
    print sol[0]
    print sol[1]
```

Comment: Huh, what did you do there? Where's the input?

Comment: @xrisk I took one extreme case.

Comment: What? How long did that take to run? 2*100 is impossible to run in a reasonable amount of time. Its ~10e300 cycles. A normal computer does 10e9 operations in 1 second.

Comment: @xrisk indeed, but this has little to do with the language itself. In fact the error you had is a reminder of the C-ish guts of Python.

Comment: Okay, cool. I guess that your solution will work. (eventually)

Comment: @xrisk btw, never use `range` if you only need to use a number once, because `range` creates a full-blown list in memory before your `for` loop even starts.

Comment: @xrisk `range` builds a list in memory, so Python throws exceptions if you pass big numbers to `range` in order to prevent memory overflows. Correct way to deal with this is to use `islice`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15725522/471899) answer for more details

Comment: @EliKorvigo, memory is of no concern - speed is.

Comment: @xrisk creating a huge list in memory takes more time than returning numbers one by one.

Comment: Okay, thanks everybody - now to figure out the real solution.

Comment: The correct way to deal with very large ranges is to use `xrange()` in python 2, or switch to python 3 (where `range()` is actually python 2's `xrange()`). `xrange()` gives you an iterator that only generates numbers as you need them.

Comment: @alexis `xrange` implementation uses a C long to store current value, hence it will overflow as well. Python 3 `range` will do, because it's based on Python (limitless) ints.