# bit operations in 32 and 64 bit machines

Tags: c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, 32bit-64bit, bitwise-operators

I have the following piece of code in C where I am trying to extract specific bits from values stored in `val1` and `val2` respectively and then store back the decimal equivalent of extracted bit to `val1` and `val2` for later comparison of val1 and val2. `nbits` gives the range of bits to be extracted here for example from 2 to 2 meaning just extract the third bit.

```
static unsigned int BIT[] = {
0x1,        0x2,        0x4,        0x8,
0x10,       0x20,       0x40,       0x80,
0x100,      0x200,      0x400,      0x800,
0x1000,     0x2000,     0x4000,     0x8000,
0x10000,    0x20000,    0x40000,    0x80000,
0x100000,   0x200000,   0x400000,   0x800000,
0x1000000,  0x2000000,  0x4000000,  0x8000000,
0x10000000, 0x20000000, 0x40000000, 0x80000000
};
int val1, val2;
unsigned long mask_val;
int nbits[2];

nbits[0] = nbits[1] = 2;
val1 = -41;
val2 = -45;

for (i = nbits[0]; i <= nbits[1]; i++)
     mask_val = mask_val|BIT[i];
val1 = (val1 & mask_val) >> nbits[0];
val2 = (val2 & mask_val) >> nbits[0];
```

This piece of code above works as desired for a 32 bit machine but gives wrong results for a 64 bit machine specially when the initial values stored in `val1` and `val2` are negative. What changes do I have to make to my code above to make it machine independent?

Comment: `int` and `long` types are not portable.  Use the `stdint.h` types, instead: `int32_t`, `uint32_t`, `int64_t`, and `uint64_t`.

Comment: @sfstewman That seems like the right answer to me, so you should probably post it as such, not just a comment

Comment: Not initializing this makes me uncomfortable: `unsigned long mask_val;` but I don't know if it is causing any of your problems.

Comment: Also why is your mask (potentially) larger than your vals? If you have a certain size val, it is no use having a larger mask is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1, not initializing mask_val will cause you problems on many compilers
2, use stdint.h and it's types for vals and mask to be system independent

```
int8_t
int16_t
int32_t
uint8_t
uint16_t
uint32_t
int64_t
uint64_t
```

3, Why not just bitshift from 0x1 instead of using the table.  ie

```
mask_val = mask_val| ( 0x1 << (i - 1) );
```

Comment: Better yet: `mask_val = ~((1U << nbits[0]) - 1) & ((1U << nbits[1]) - 1);` and just get rid of the `for` loop.

Comment: I also found that changing the datatype of val1 and val2 to unsigned int solved the problem

Comment: Actually, minor error with that expression. I think this works better: `mask_val = ~((1U << nbits[0]) - 1) & ((1U << (nbits[1] + 1)) - 1);`. The first one failed when `nbits[0] == nbits[1]`.

Comment: @srsci, just curious are you aware that ints are stored in 2's compliment(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).  I ask because I am get the feeling from your above post your expecting -42 to contain the bit pattern of binary 42.

Comment: yes i realized my foolishness in this regard. I need to do more reading regarding this. Thanks for pointing this out to me

Answer (score 1):

While I was developing various versions of your code, others essentially stated the same things I show below.

I think the reason your code worked on the 32-bit version was a fluke; apparently on that system your uninitialized mask_val just happened to be zero, you were "lucky".

Below I show a progression of three versions of your own code.  First shows the code essentially unchanged, but initializing mask_val to 0, and using a typedef for whatever type you want the code to run with.  Second is the same, but without the BIT[] table.  Third eliminates the loop.

```
#if 0
#include <stdio.h>

typedef long long valTy;

int main()
{
static unsigned int BIT[] = {
0x1,        0x2,        0x4,        0x8,
0x10,       0x20,       0x40,       0x80,
0x100,      0x200,      0x400,      0x800,
0x1000,     0x2000,     0x4000,     0x8000,
0x10000,    0x20000,    0x40000,    0x80000,
0x100000,   0x200000,   0x400000,   0x800000,
0x1000000,  0x2000000,  0x4000000,  0x8000000,
0x10000000, 0x20000000, 0x40000000, 0x80000000
};
valTy val1, val2;
valTy mask_val;
int i, nbits[2];

printf("\n");

nbits[0] = nbits[1] = 2;
val1 = -41;
val2 = -45;

printf("    val1 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val1, (long long)val1);
printf("    val2 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val2, (long long)val2);
printf("\n");

mask_val = 0;
for (i = nbits[0]; i <= nbits[1]; i++)
    mask_val = mask_val|BIT[i];
printf("mask_val = 0x%016llx\n\n", (long long)mask_val);
val1 = (val1 & mask_val) >> nbits[0];
val2 = (val2 & mask_val) >> nbits[0];

printf("    val1 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val1, (long long)val1);
printf("    val2 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val2, (long long)val2);
printf("\n");
}

#endif




#if 0
#include <stdio.h>

typedef long long valTy;
#define BIT(bitnum) (1<<bitnum)

int main()
{
valTy val1, val2;
valTy mask_val;
int i, nbits[2];

printf("\n");

nbits[0] = nbits[1] = 2;
val1 = -41;
val2 = -45;

printf("    val1 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val1, (long long)val1);
printf("    val2 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val2, (long long)val2);
printf("\n");

mask_val = 0;
for (i = nbits[0]; i <= nbits[1]; i++)
    mask_val = mask_val | BIT(i);
printf("mask_val = 0x%016llx\n\n", (long long)mask_val);
val1 = (val1 & mask_val) >> nbits[0];
val2 = (val2 & mask_val) >> nbits[0];

printf("    val1 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val1, (long long)val1);
printf("    val2 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val2, (long long)val2);
printf("\n");
}

#endif

#include <stdio.h>

typedef long long valTy;
#define BIT(bitnum) (1<<bitnum)

int main()
{
valTy val1, val2;
valTy mask_val;
int i, nbits[2];

printf("\n");

nbits[0] = nbits[1] = 2;
val1 = -41;
val2 = -45;

printf("    val1 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val1, (long long)val1);
printf("    val2 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val2, (long long)val2);
printf("\n");

mask_val = 0;
{
    valTy maskTop = ((BIT(nbits[0])-1)<<1)|1;
    valTy maskBottom = BIT(nbits[1])-1;
    mask_val = maskTop & ~maskBottom;
}
printf("mask_val = 0x%016llx\n\n", (long long)mask_val);
val1 = (val1 & mask_val) >> nbits[0];
val2 = (val2 & mask_val) >> nbits[0];

printf("    val1 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val1, (long long)val1);
printf("    val2 = 0x%016llx (%lld)\n", (long long)val2, (long long)val2);
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the conclusion that I came to.  Negative values of `val1` and `val2` cause the higher-order bits to be set (twos-complement notation and all), and are probably exposing an uninitialized `mask_val`.

Answer (score 0):

the code is still working as written but I suspect your sign bit is higher than the 32 bit mark. Please refer to this post and let me know if it is helpful:
[What is the bit size of long on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from the fact that `mask_val` isn't initialized. You should initialize it with 0 in order to ensure no bit is set before your loop starts.