# sizeof unsigned int in microsoft x64-compiler

Tags: c, 64-bit, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the bit size of long on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows)

Why is it that when I compile as x64 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4`? <s>Doesn't it must</s> Shouldn't it be `8 == sizeof(int)`? I change platform in configuration manager and in command_line_compiler all settings are x64, but size of `unsigned int = 4`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Note that even on Unix 64-bit systems, `sizeof(int) == sizeof(unsigned int)` and both are 4 (not 8).  On Unix, `long` (and `unsigned long`) are 64-bit quantities; so too are `long long` and `unsigned long long`.  This is the LP64 (`long` and pointers are 64-bit) model.  Windows 64 leaves both `int` and `long` at 32 bits, and only `long long` and pointers are 64-bit quantities (LLP64 — `long long` and pointers are 64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't it must = 8 = sizeof(int)

No, that need not be. The size of the various integer types is up to the implementation, the standard only prescribes (in section 5.2.4.2) some minimal ranges.

For example, a `char` must have at least 8 bits, a `short int` and an `int` (also the `unsigned` versions thereof, which must have the same size and alignment requirements as the corresponding signed type) must have at least 16 bits, `long` must have at least 32 bits, and `long long` at least 64.

Even on 64-bit systems, it is common that `int` (and `unsigned int`) are 32-bit types.

Whether a `long` is 32 bits or 64 depends, it's 64 bits on most (if not all) 64-bit linux systems, and 32 bits on Windows 64 bit.

Comment: Always 32-bit on Windows 64.

Comment: Also, you should mention that an unsigned and a signed integer type of the same name (int and unsigned int, long and unsigned long, etc.) should have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Language standard doesn't tell about the `sizeof(int)` or any data types. Its implementation defined.

But it should follow this rule:

```
1<=sizeof(char) < sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) < sizeof(long long)
```

Comment: “1<=sizeof(char)” -> The standard tells us a little bit more than that (C99 6.5.3.4:3). “sizeof(char) < sizeof(short)” -> The standard does not say that. “sizeof(long) < sizeof(long long)” -> The standard does not say that.

Answer (score -1):

> Doesn't it must = 8 = sizeof(int)?

If this is, in correct English, supposed to mean "should it not have a size equal to that of int"? then the answer is: **yes, the standard requires that an unsigned integral type and its corresponding signed type be of the same size.** If that's not the case, then Visual Studio's compiler is not conformant (surprise, surprise...).

However, it's possible that *both* `int` and `unsigned int` are 4 byte long - there's nothing particularly strange in that, even on a 64-bit implementation. Probably `long` or `long long` (and their unsigned counterparts) are 8 byte long.