# Is it not guaranteed that long or long long can store greater numbers than int?

Tags: c++, types, integer, long-integer

In my assignment, it says

> Do not add `long int` or `long long` private members to accomplish this as there is no guarantee that either can actually store larger numbers than an `int`.

I know that `int` has a maximum of 2<sup>31</sup>-1 and `long long` has a maximum of 2<sup>63</sup>-1. Can someone give me an example to me why the given sentence is true?

Comment: Actually it's `(2**32)-1` and `(2**64)-1`.

Comment: If you need size guarantees, use the types defined in cstdint. You won't risk relying on implementation defined behavior, and it's easier to understand what the code means when reading it. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: your limits are correct for unsigned integers; the poster's are correct for signed integers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means exactly what it says. There's no guarantee that a `long long` can store more numbers than an `int`. It's *at least as big*, but it can be the same.

> I know that int has a maximum of 2^31-1 and long long has a maximum of 2^63-1

This can be true for some platform, with some compiler, but it's not always the same. C++ doesn't guarantee either.

#### 3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]

> 2) There are five standard signed integer types : “`signed char`”,
>   “`short int`”, “`int`”, “`long int`”, and “`long long int`”. In this list,
>   **each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it** in
>   the list. [...] (emphasis mine)

Comment: But I thought long long can store any value in the range of –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: @user44322 what's your reference for that?

Comment: I think in C++11, `long long` is guaranteed to be bigger or something.

Comment: @chris "at least" - added the reference.

Comment: @user44322 the standard reference preceds the one from MS. See the edit.

Comment: So you guys are saying that if I use long long, there is a chance that my teacher is using a compiler that doesn't support long long to its actual value.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, Yup, I looked through myself and found nothing. I swear I heard it had to be bigger somewhere, though :/

Comment: @user44322 no. We're saying that what you mean by "actual value" isn't correct. A correct actual value follows the specs in the standard. It's correct for `sizeof(int)` to be equal to `sizeof(long long int)`.

Comment: I meant, if I put a value into long long like 2^63-1, it might give an overflow on the submission server even if it doesn't overflow on my computer.

Comment: To clarify: `char` must be at least 8 bits. `short` and `int` must be at least 16 bits. `long int` must be at least 32 bits. `long long int` must be at least 64 bits. You could probably create a conforming implementation in which they were all 64 bits (though C-style I/O assumes `int` is larger than `char`). But no -- 2^63-1 will *not* overflow a long long int on any machine (at least with a conforming implementation -- and I've never heard even a suggestion of an implementation that didn't conform in this respect).

Comment: Well, if I use the types defined in cstdint as suggested by Reuben Morais then it will guarantee to be able to contain 2^63-1?

Comment: If you use `long long` or `int64_t` (presuming it exists) you're guaranteed that either will hold 2^63-1.

Comment: But according to Luchian Grigore, there is no guarantee that 2^63-1 can be stored in long long.

Comment: @user44322, if you're in doubt check out the values in `<limits>` `std::numeric_limits`.

Comment: @user44322: In this care, Luchian is wrong. It's a rare occasion -- probably want to write it on the calendar or something!

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't see how or where it's guaranteed that a long long int can store 2^63-1. I agree about `int64_t`.

Comment: The C++ standard refers to the C standard. Annex E of the C standard specifies the minimum magnitudes for long long as:: `#define LLONG_MAX +9223372036854775807` and `#define LLONG_MIN     -9223372036854775807`. (technically Annex E is "informative" -- the same information is also somewhere normative though -- I'm just too lazy to find it at the moment).

Comment: @JerryCoffin where is this referral?

Comment: §18.3.3/1, among other places.

Comment: @JerryCoffin /2 - "The types of the constants
defined by macros in <climits> are not required to match the types to which the macros refer."

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yes -- that doesn't mean the values may be wrong. It means that (for example) they're free to specify SHRT_MIN as `-32768`, even though `-32768` isn't a `short` (the literal doesn't include the `-`, so the literal itself is `32768`, which won't fit in a 16-bit short, so it'll be `int` if that's 32 bits, or `long` if `int` is only 16 bits).

Answer (score 2):

The C standard specifies two relevant criteria:

- `sizeof(char) ≤ sizeof(short) ≤ sizeof(int) ≤ sizeof(long) ≤ sizeof(long long) ≤ sizeof(uintmax_t)`

  This is specified indirectly in ISU/IEC 9899:2011, §6.2.5 Types, ¶8: *For any two integer types with the same signedness and different integer conversion rank
  (see 6.3.1.1), the range of values of the type with smaller integer conversion rank is a
  subrange of the values of the other type.*
- The minimum permitted value for the maxima of the types (ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`):

  - `SCHAR_MAX` ≥ 127 // 2<sup>7</sup>-1
  - `SHRT_MAX` ≥ 32,767 // 2<sup>15</sup>-1
  - `INT_MAX` ≥ 32,767 // 2<sup>15</sup>-1
  - `LONG_MAX` ≥ 2,147,483,647 // 2<sup>31</sup>-1
  - `LLONG_MAX` ≥ 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 // 2<sup>63</sup>-1

The quote is formally correct; it is possible to devise systems where `long` does not store a larger range than `int` — indeed, this is the case on most 32-bit systems (all the ones I know of), and also true on Windows 64.  It is less likely to be accurate w.r.t `long long`; I know of no system where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long long)` (and, because of the inequality quoted, `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`).  On most Unix 64-bit systems, `sizeof(int) == 4`, `sizeof(long) == 8`, and `sizeof(long long) == 8`; on Windows 64, `sizeof(long) == 4` and only `long long` (or `__int64`) is a 64-bit type.

Comment: The common combinations even have names, as you're aware from a previous answer of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/384672/5987

Comment: I am indeed aware of the names; I decided not to use them here, though maybe that was a mistake.